# Python: determine if all items of a list are the same item

Tags: python, list

In some of my code I put a series of objects in a list and I build an additional list out of  their attributes, which is a string. I need to determine if all the items in this second list have the exact same value, without knowing beforehand which value it is, and return a bool so that I can do different things in my code depending on the result.

I can't know the names of the properties beforehand, that is why I'm trying to make something as generic as possible.

To make the example clear, an ideal function, called "all_same" would work like this:

```
>>> property_list = ["one", "one", "one"]
>>> all_same(property_list)
True
>>> property_list = ["one", "one", "two"]
>>> all_same(property_list)
False
```

I was thinking of making a list of unique elements and then check if its length is 1, but I'm not sure if it's the most elegant solution out there.

Comment: Just realized that I asked the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844801/check-if-all-elements-in-a-list-are-identical. How do I link these two questions?

Comment: Heh, first question I've seen where an earlier question is the duplicate. Time does sometimes work in reverse.

Comment: The title of this one sounds like the asker wants to check *identity* (`a is b`), not *equality* (`a == b`)

Answer (score 176, accepted):

```
def all_same(items):
    return all(x == items[0] for x in items)
```

**Example:**

```
>>> def all_same(items):
...     return all(x == items[0] for x in items)
...
>>> property_list = ["one", "one", "one"]
>>> all_same(property_list)
True
>>> property_list = ["one", "one", "two"]
>>> all_same(property_list)
False
>>> all_same([])
True
```

Comment: `len(set(items)) == 1` is faster.

Comment: This answer has a few shortcommings: it only works with indexables and with equality (and no identity). Hence a slightly improved version:

import operator

def same(iterable, compare=operator.eq, value_on_empty=True):
    gen = iter(iterable)
    start = next(gen, value_on_empty)
    return all(compare(start, x) for x in gen)

This will work with unsized iterable such as generators, allow you to specify what "is the same" mean and what to do on an empty value.

Comment: @e-satis improve the answer with that version.

Comment: This will raise a `KeyError` if your list is empty, when it should return `True`.

Answer (score 64):

You could cheat and use `set`:

```
def all_same( items ):
    return len( set( items ) ) == 1 #== len( items )
```

or you could use:

```
def all_same( items ):
    return all( map(lambda x: x == items[0], items ) )
```

or if you're dealing with an iterable instead of a list:

```
def all_same( iterable ):
    it_copy = tee( iterable, 1 )
    return len( set( it_copy) ) == 1
```

Comment: The set would have just one item, the list would have N.

Comment: You could use generator expression in the 2nd code. `all(x == items[0] for x in items)`.

Comment: len(set(items)) == 1 definitely most idiomatic.

Comment: It is also much faster: `a = ["a"]*100; a[53]="b"`. `%timeit len(set(a)) == 1` --> 2.83us per loop. `%timeit all(x==a[0] for x in a)` --> 7.78us per loop.

Comment: @muraveill What machine did you use and can you reproduce those results? I get the opposite relative ordering on both machines I could try: the `all()` approach is about 3 times faster than the `set()` approach.

Comment: It was an old MacBook Air. I did it again on a MacBook Pro: `len(set(a))`: 1.81 µs per loop, `all(x==a[0] for x in a)`: 5.26 µs per loop.

Answer (score 11):

Best way to do this is to use Python sets.You need to define `all_same` like this:

```
def all_same(items):
    return len(set(items)) < 2
```

**Test:**

```
>>> def all_same(items):
...     return len(set(items)) < 2
... 
>>> 
>>> property_list = ["one", "one", "one"]
>>> all_same(property_list)
True
>>> property_list = ["one", "one", "two"]
>>> all_same(property_list)
False
>>> property_list = []
>>> all_same(property_list)
True
```

Comment: This did not work for me, as elements of my list are dictionaries and can not be hashed

Answer (score 10):

I originally interpreted you to be testing identity ("the same item"), but you're really testing *equality* ("same value").  (If you were testing identity, use *is* instead of ==.)

```
def all_same(items):
  it = iter(items)
  for first in it:
    break
  else:
    return True  # empty case, note all([]) == True
  return all(x == first for x in it)
```

The above works on any iterable, not just lists, otherwise you could use:

```
def all_same(L):
  return all(x == L[0] for x in L)
```

(But, IMHO, you might as well use the general version—it works perfectly fine on lists.)

Comment: +1 I'll have to remember that recipe.

Comment: @katrielalex: Then you have to try/except for StopIteration; at that point, it's equivalent behavior and the same length.

Comment: I prefer `try: first = next(it) except StopIteration: return True` -- I think the flow is clearer -- but same difference, really.

Comment: @Roger: sorry, noticed that and deleted too late. Indeed! =)

Comment: I like this solution. Even if the OP asked only for lists, generators are so pervasive now in Python that it's better not to assume that the input is a sequence. Note that you can simplify it a bit with Python >= 2.6: first = next(it, None)

Comment: @tokland: Doesn't work, what if you want to pass `[None, 42]` to the function?  (You can use a sentinel object that is only ever used in this function, but way more hassle than it's worth here.)

Comment: @Roger: if you pass [None, 42] you get False, as you'd expect. Note that the sentinel is never actually used if the iterable is empty.

Comment: @tokland: I know the sentinel is never used, that's why I placed None first: you can't tell if the None you get is from the list or from the second param.  Could you post code? (A new answer?  Since it would also answer this question.)  Obviously we're imagining different things.

Comment: @Roger: There is my answer, I think you'll recognize the last assert ;-) you are right that usually sentinels cannot be a potential element in the input, but it does not apply here. Or am I missing something?

Comment: (response in comment on [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787908/python-determine-if-all-items-of-a-list-are-the-same-item/3789000#3789000), posted before asked! :P)

Answer (score 5):

This works both for sequences and iterables:

```
def all_same(items):
  it = iter(items)
  first = next(it, None)
  return all(x == first for x in it)
```

Comment: Ah, I was imagining you'd check `first is None` instead of letting this fall-through.  It does give the right result, but I prefer to treat this an error/"exceptional circumstance" instead of depending on later code to silently do the right thing.

Comment: I know I am very unpythonic in this opinion, but I don't like that a pretty single line turns into four because I have to catch an exception (I speak in general, you used a for/break in you answer). Yeah, I known about EAFP, but still, if I can avoid it... Thanks for the +1, though :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is likely to be faster if you know values are in a list.

```
def all_same(values):
    return values.count(values[0]) == len(values)
```

Answer (score -2):

I created this snippet of code for that same issue after thinking it over. I'm not exactly sure if it works for every scenario though.

```
def all_same(list):
    list[0]*len(list) == list
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work at all. E.g. `test_list=[1, 1]` and `all_same(test_list)` returns `False` because `test_list[0] = 1` and `len(test_list) = 2` so the results is just `1 * 2 = 2`. Then you test `2 == test_list`, which is not True.