# Check if all elements in a list are identical

Tags: python, algorithm, comparison

I need a function which takes in a `list` and outputs `True` if all elements in the input list evaluate as equal to each other using the standard equality operator and `False` otherwise.

I feel it would be best to iterate through the list comparing adjacent elements and then `AND` all the resulting Boolean values. But I'm not sure what's the most Pythonic way to do that.

Comment: Equal as in `a == b` or identical as in `a is b`?

Comment: Should the solution handle empty lists? If so, what should be returned?

Comment: Equal as in a == b. Should handle empty list, and return True.

Comment: Although I know it's slower than some of the other recommendations, I'm surprised `functools.reduce(operator.eq, a)` hasn't been suggested.

Comment: If the elements to compare are only numerical datatype, (Int, Double, Float). Given a List of numerical data type, extract the *minimum* and  *maximum*, then return *maximum* == *minimum* and it is done.

You can (over compute the returning) returning  *maximum*  -  *minimum*  ==  0

Comment: @FrancoGil that requires iterating over the list twice. It would be slower than most (if not all) methods suggested here. And you'd need to check for the empty list. And like you said, it will silently give the wrong result for a list of strings.

Comment: @ user2846495  `functools.reduce(operator.eq, a)` would not work. for example with the list `[True, False, False]`, it would return `((True == False) == False)` which is `True`. Whereas the function should return False (because the elements are not all equal)

Comment: @Boris You can get both the maximum and minimum in one pass if you write your own loop instead of using Python's `max()` and `min()`, and further optimize it like https://www.siderite.dev/blog/finding-simultaneously-minimum-and.html/

Comment: @Leponzo `max()` and `min()` are implemented in C on CPython. I think you would get a significant slowdown implementing it yourself.

Comment: @Boris I was referring to your comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844801/check-if-all-elements-in-a-list-are-identical?noredirect=1#comment114624538_3844801).

Comment: @Leponzo I'm saying if you implement getting the min/max in one pass in Python, it might still be faster to just call the functions and iterate over the list twice (for certain sized lists at least) because they are implemented in C.

Comment: why not just use `more_itertools.all_equal`?  https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.all_equal

Answer (score 619, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) (see [the `itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)):

```
from itertools import groupby

def all_equal(iterable):
    g = groupby(iterable)
    return next(g, True) and not next(g, False)
```

or without `groupby`:

```
def all_equal(iterator):
    iterator = iter(iterator)
    try:
        first = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        return True
    return all(first == x for x in iterator)
```

---

There are a number of alternative one-liners you might consider:

1. Converting the input to a set and checking that it only has one or zero (in case the input is empty) items

   ```
   def all_equal2(iterator):
       return len(set(iterator)) <= 1
   ```
2. Comparing against the input list without the first item

   ```
   def all_equal3(lst):
       return lst[:-1] == lst[1:]
   ```
3. [Counting how many times the first item appears in the list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3844948/)

   ```
   def all_equal_ivo(lst):
       return not lst or lst.count(lst[0]) == len(lst)
   ```
4. [Comparing against a list of the first element repeated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3844931/)

   ```
   def all_equal_6502(lst):
       return not lst or [lst[0]]*len(lst) == lst
   ```

But they have some downsides, namely:

1. `all_equal` and `all_equal2` can use any iterators, but the others must take a sequence input, typically concrete containers like a list or tuple.
2. `all_equal` and `all_equal3` stop as soon as a difference is found (what is called "[short circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)"), whereas all the alternatives require iterating over the entire list, even if you can tell that the answer is `False` just by looking at the first two elements.
3. In `all_equal2` the content must be [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable). A list of lists will raise a `TypeError` for example.
4. `all_equal2` (in the worst case) and `all_equal_6502` create a copy of the list, meaning you need to use double the memory.

On Python 3.9, using [`perfplot`](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot), we get these timings (lower `Runtime [s]` is better):

[image: for a list with a difference in the first two elements, groupby is fastest][image: for a list with no differences, count(l[0]) is fastest]

Comment: Don't forget memory usage analysis for very large arrays, a native solution which optimizes away calls to `obj.__eq__` when `lhs is rhs`, and out-of-order optimizations to allow short circuiting sorted lists more quickly.

Comment: In case the intuition on checkEqual3 wasn't immediately obvious to anyone else: all items are the same if `first == second and second == third and ...`

Comment: This is brilliantly fast. Clever approach too. Helpful suggestion for those implementing with `pytest`, you should return the result before asserting True/False. (Wrap this function in another.)

Comment: @Boris: What is the code for these charts?

Comment: @ChaimG if you click on "Edit", the code is hidden in a comment in the text of the answer.

Comment: You could make a further improvement to the version without `groupby` by using `eq` from the [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module. These functions will be slightly faster than writing it yourself because they are implemented in C within the interpreter.

Comment: In `all_equal` you can use `first = next(iterator, None)` to avoid `try/except` construction.

Comment: I prefer  pairwise comparison with zip(lst, lst[1:])

Comment: To make this work with `pd.NA`, just [add an exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59543818/357313).

Comment: Since you're already using `itertools`, you can actually also use `islice` to avoid that first call to `next`, which actually allows you to inline the entire thing: `return not next(islice(groupby(iterable), 1, None), False)`

Comment: Is there any way you can upload the code which produced these figures to github or something? It would be interesting to add some others to it.

Answer (score 392):

A solution faster than using set() that works on sequences (not iterables) is to simply count the first element. This assumes the list is non-empty (but that's trivial to check, and decide yourself what the outcome should be on an empty list)

```
x.count(x[0]) == len(x)
```

some simple benchmarks:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('len(set(s1))<=1', 's1=[1]*5000', number=10000)
1.4383411407470703
>>> timeit.timeit('len(set(s1))<=1', 's1=[1]*4999+[2]', number=10000)
1.4765670299530029
>>> timeit.timeit('s1.count(s1[0])==len(s1)', 's1=[1]*5000', number=10000)
0.26274609565734863
>>> timeit.timeit('s1.count(s1[0])==len(s1)', 's1=[1]*4999+[2]', number=10000)
0.25654196739196777
```

Comment: OMG, this is 6 times faster than the set solution! (280 million elements/sec vs 45 million elements/sec on my laptop). Why??? And is there any way to modify it so that it short circuits (I guess not...)

Comment: I guess list.count has a highly optimized C implementation, and the length of the list is stored internally, so len() is cheap as well. There's not a way to short-circuit count() since you will need to really check all elements to get the correct count.

Comment: Can I change it to: `x.count(next(x)) == len(x)` so that it works for any container x? Ahh.. nm, just saw that .count is only available for sequences.. Why isn't it implemented for other builtin containers? Is counting inside a dictionary inherently less meaningful than inside a list?

Comment: An iterator may not have a length. E.g. it can be infinite or just dynamically generated. You can only find its length by converting it to a list which takes away most of the iterators advantages

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was why `count` isn't implemented for iterables, not why `len` isn't available for iterators. The answer is probably that it's just an oversight. But it's irrelavant for us because default `.count()` for sequences is very slow (pure python). The reason your solution is so fast is that it relies on the C-implemented `count` provided by `list`. So I suppose whichever iterable happens to implement `count` method in C will benefit from your approach.

Comment: @IvovanderWijk Among the faster approaches is this one: `timeit.timeit('all(i == s1[0] for i in set(s1))', 's1=[1]*5000', number=10000)`. It clocks in at 0.39 ms on my system while the count == len clocks in at 0.16 ms.

Comment: This unfortunately does not work for `numpy` arrays.

Comment: On my machine running 3.8.10, the difference is even starker - the `.count` approach is about 13 times as fast.

Comment: The problem here is this is not lazy evaluated, and perhaps worse, it isn't that obvious that it isn't lazy evaluated either. (Requires some active thinking, which is always less good than being immediately obvious.) Also, while it's great to find something which has 10x performance compared to some other solution, if performance is a problem using Python by default is the wrong choice. I don't understand why people make these arguments while missing the broader point.

Answer (score 238):

[edit: This answer addresses the currently top-voted `itertools.groupby` (which is a good answer) answer later on.]

Without rewriting the program, the most asymptotically performant ***and*** most readable way is as follows:

```
all(x==myList[0] for x in myList)
```

(Yes, this even works with the empty list! This is because this is one of the few cases where python has lazy semantics.)

This will fail at the earliest possible time, so it is asymptotically optimal (expected time is approximately O(#uniques) rather than O(N), but worst-case time still O(N)). This is assuming you have not seen the data before...

(If you care about performance but not that much about performance, you can just do the usual standard optimizations first, like hoisting the `myList[0]` constant out of the loop and adding clunky logic for the edge case, though this is something the python compiler might eventually learn how to do and thus one should not do it unless absolutely necessary, as it destroys readability for minimal gain.)

If you care slightly more about performance, this is twice as fast as above but a bit more verbose:

```
def allEqual(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    
    try:
        firstItem = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        return True
        
    for x in iterator:
        if x!=firstItem:
            return False
    return True
```

If you care even more about performance (but not enough to rewrite your program), use the currently top-voted `itertools.groupby` answer, which is twice as fast as `allEqual` because it is probably optimized C code. (According to the docs, it should (similar to this answer) not have any memory overhead because the lazy generator is never evaluated into a list... which one might be worried about, but the pseudocode shows that the grouped 'lists' are actually lazy generators.)

If you care even more about performance read on...

---

sidenotes regarding performance, because the other answers are talking about it for some unknown reason:

... if you have seen the data before and are likely using a collection data structure of some sort, and you really care about performance, **you can get `.isAllEqual()` for free O(1) by augmenting your structure with a `Counter` that is updated with every insert/delete/etc. operation and just checking if it's of the form `{something:someCount}` i.e. `len(counter.keys())==1`; alternatively you can keep a Counter on the side in a separate variable. This is provably better than anything else up to constant factor.** Perhaps you can also use python's FFI with `ctypes` with your chosen method, and perhaps with a heuristic (like if it's a sequence with **getitem**, then checking first element, last element, then elements in-order).

Of course, there's something to be said for readability.

Comment: This works, but it's a bit (1.5x) slower than @KennyTM `checkEqual1`. I'm not sure why.

Comment: max: Likely because I did not bother to perform the optimization `first=myList[0]` `all(x==first for x in myList)`, perhaps

Comment: I think that myList[0] is evaluated with each iteration.

    >>> timeit.timeit('all([y == x[0] for y in x])', 'x=[1] * 4000', number=10000)
    2.707076672740641
    >>> timeit.timeit('x0 = x[0]; all([y == x0 for y in x])', 'x=[1] * 4000', number=10000)
    2.0908854261426484

Comment: I should of course clarify that the optimization `first=myList[0]` will throw an `IndexError` on an empty list, so commenters who were talking about that optimization I mentioned will have to deal with the edge-case of an empty list. However the original is fine (`x==myList[0]` is fine within the `all` because it is never evaluated if the list is empty).

Comment: This is clearly the right way to to it. If you want speed in every case, use something like numpy.

Comment: For null lists, do you mean this will return `False`? I'm not able to replicate if so. If you wish to detect a null list, how would you modify the above? I have been using `if myList and all(x==myList[0] for x in myList)`?

Comment: @Josmoor98: I mean the empty list `[]`, which I assume you mean too (if the list can be None, that's another issue and must be treated separately), and that `all(x==y[0] for x in myList)` will be true for inputs myList=... `[]`, `[1]`, `[1,1]`, `['a','a','a']`, `[[1],[1]]`, `[(1,),(1,)]`, and even strings '"zzz"'. It will be false for inputs like `[1,2]`, or anything where two elements a,b don't return `a.__eq__(b)` or equivalent. [continued]

Comment: @Josmoor98: [continued] If your var can be None, be aware `bool([])==False` and `bool(None)==False`. Stylistically if were to encapsulate this answer in a function, such "are null" checks should be made outside the function e.g. `def allEqual(myList): all(.....)`, and later on `if myVar!=None and allEqual(myVar):`

Comment: In my testing, this is much slower than the `set` approach for input that meets the criteria, which in turn is much slower than the `.count` approach. However, it is capable of short-circuiting.

Comment: The biggest problem, which many answers have, is the arbitrary dependency on `myList[0]`.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant How is that a problem?

Comment: @KellyBundy On a technical level, it's fragile. If you care about readability and style then in my opinion it falls short on both of those metrics as well. But that's just my opinion. I suspect most experienced engineers would spot the code smell in a code review.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant How is it "fragile"? It looks perfectly fine (except for the lack of spaces surrounding `==`).

Comment: @KellyBundy Please stop replying to every comment I make on these posts. You clearly don't have enough experience with Python to understand the points being made so I don't know why you are insistent on replying to every comment I make. It is fragile for several reasons. Firstly it is not obvious what it is doing, it is not readable. Secondly it takes 10 lines to achieve what can be achieved in a single line. Like many of the other answers posted here it's just not a good solution in any way. The only purpose this serves is to obscure the good answers.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant I reply to unclear or wrong stuff, that's all. How was I supposed to know you meant the **second** solution, which doesn't even say `myList[0]`? Anyway, it's not unreadable at all. It took me ~9 seconds (I actually measured) to read and understand it (the second solution) because it is so obvious. And the purpose it serves is a good one and explicitly stated right above it. How do you justify adding a bad 18-liner to your own answer after you complained about this alright 10-liner? Still a mystery what you even mean with *"dependency on `myList[0]`"*, btw. I'd like to know

Comment: `myList` exists in one of the lines above the line shown in the question(s). The use of `myList[0]` is essentially hoisting a special value out of the enclosing scope. It isn't totally horrendous, but it's also not particularly nice. Put another way, it **should** (in my opinion) be possible and easy to check if all elements produced by an iterator are equal, but it **isn't**. There are some solutions which at least are quite "Pythonic" this one is sort of half way there but not quite as good as some other options.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Not sure what you mean with "essentially hoisting", but the only access across scopes is `myList` and that's a completely normal thing to do. We access things from outer scopes all the time.

Comment: Let me try rephrasing: What relevance does the value of the first element of the iterable have? The answer is "none". The value of that particular element is not of any relevance to answering the question "are all elements equal". What this code does is instead ask the question "are all elements equal to element with index 0". It's not the same question, but gives the same result. By "hoisting" I mean this - it is pulling an irrelevant value out of the list. The code **not only** speaks about **"the list"** but also speaks about **"the first element of the list"**. Double usage -> redundant

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant It's absolutely not "none". You have to implement the functionality **somehow**. And comparing all values to the first is the most natural choice. It's what you'd do in real life, too. If I said I'll show you a sequence of colors and you shall tell me if they're all equal, and the first color I show you is red, you'd set your mind to "red" and just check whether all remaining colors are also red, wouldn't you? Also, index 0 is guaranteed to exist when you want to do a comparison. *"What this code does is instead ask the question"*? Nonsense. It **answers** a question.

Comment: @KellyBundy Sorry but your last comment shows a complete lack of understanding of the entire point I just made so I can't really reply to it

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant No, you just demonstrated that you don't understand how programming works. Maybe look into declarative programming languages, that appears to be what you're looking for. Python clearly isn't for you.

Answer (score 75):

Convert your input into a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
len(set(the_list)) <= 1
```

Using `set` removes all duplicate elements. `<= 1` is so that it correctly returns `True` when the input is empty.

This requires that all the elements in your input are [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable). You'll get a `TypeError` if you pass in a list of lists for example.

Comment: Why should an empty list be `True` instead of `False`. It will depend on what the client wants. In my particular case, yes, I also happen to want `True` for an empty input. But this is specific to my current problem.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Because that's the standard. See [Vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) and note that for example Python's `all([])` is also `True`, for that reason. And if someone does want to deviate from the standard, they can simply use `== 1`.

Comment: @KellyBundy I'm not talking about that. I am making the point that since you don't know what the calling client wants you cannot know in advance which is 'correct' from the client point of view

Answer (score 49):

You can convert the list to a set. A set cannot have duplicates. So if all the elements in the original list are identical, the set will have just one element.

```
if len(set(input_list)) == 1:
    # input_list has all identical elements.
```

Comment: this is nice but it doesn't short circuit and you have to calculate the length of the resulting list.

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth: Still a noob in py. Don't even know what a short circut in py means :)

Comment: @codaddict. It means that even if the first two elements are distinct, it will still complete the entire search. it also uses O(k) extra space where k is the number of distinct elements in the list.

Comment: Why the hell does this work faster than the naive manual iteration through all elements?? It has to build a set after all! But when I profiled this function, it worked 13 times faster than the naive implementation `for i in range(1, len(input_list)): if input_list[i-1] != input_list[i]: return False #otherwise return True` I set `input_list = ['x'] * 100000000`

Comment: @max. because building the set happens in C and you have a bad implementation. You should at least do it in a generator expression. See KennyTM's answer for how to do it correctly without using a set.

Comment: This is the nicest, most readable answer from all here.  Maybe not the most efficient, but it's not always that important.

Comment: This returns `False` if your list is empty, when it should return `True`. It also requires all your elements to be hashable.

Comment: I don't think an empty list should return True at all, False for that use case is completely expected.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's correct for an empty list to return `True` or `False`. If it's the wrong way around then it's for client code to handle that case, most likely by wrapping this is a new function and handling an empty list before calling this code. In other words: One person might want `True` while another wants `False`. There's no way to know which is correct, other than doing less work is "more correct". The **biggest** issue with this is the requirement for hash to be defined, which is a burden.

Answer (score 24):

For what it's worth, this came up on the [python-ideas mailing list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2016-October/042734.html) recently.  It turns out that there is an [itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) for doing this already:<sup>1</sup>

```
def all_equal(iterable):
    "Returns True if all the elements are equal to each other"
    g = groupby(iterable)
    return next(g, True) and not next(g, False)
```

Supposedly it performs very nicely and has a few nice properties.

1. Short-circuits:  It will stop consuming items from the iterable as soon as it finds the first non-equal item.
2. Doesn't require items to be hashable.
3. It is lazy and only requires O(1) additional memory to do the check.

<sup><sup>1</sup>In other words, I can't take the credit for coming up with the solution -- nor can I take credit for even *finding* it.</sup>

Comment: `return next(g, f := next(g, g)) == f` (from py3.8 of course)

Comment: To make this work with `pd.NA`, just [add an exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59543818/357313).

Comment: This recipe is slightly flawed and wasteful in that `next(g, True)` always returns `True` and consequently the expression doesn't short-circuit immediately when the given iterable is empty. It can be made more efficient with `return not (next(g, False) and next(g, False))` instead.

Answer (score 12):

This is a simple way of doing it:

```
result = mylist and all(mylist[0] == elem for elem in mylist)
```

This is slightly more complicated, it incurs function call overhead, but the semantics are more clearly spelled out:

```
def all_identical(seq):
    if not seq:
        # empty list is False.
        return False
    first = seq[0]
    return all(first == elem for elem in seq)
```

Comment: You can avoid a redundant comparison here by using `for elem in mylist[1:]`. Doubt it improves speed much though since I guess `elem[0] is elem[0]` so the interpreter can probably do that comparison very quickly.

Comment: Shouldn't an empty list be `True`? Why manually invert the True/False value, when this is answering a different question to a different problem.

Answer (score 11):

This is another option, faster than `len(set(x))==1` for long lists (uses short circuit)

```
def constantList(x):
    return x[:1]*len(x) == x
```

Comment: It is 3 times slower than the set solution on my computer, ignoring short circuit. So if the unequal element is found on average in the first third of the list, it's faster on average.

Comment: And uses double the memory?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant: not really... temporarily allocates `O(n)` memory but the allocated list will just be of `n` pointers to the same element `x[0]`. Note that even say a floating point number takes a huge amount of memory in Python (compared to say C++ is about 3x) and list elements are 8 bytes (they're just pointers).
The reason for the speed is that both loops (the one initializing lists elements and the one doing the comparison) are running in C and not as python code (and python code is really, really, REALLY slow compared to C).

Comment: So it uses double the memory

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant: no... it uses 8*n bytes of memory that is normally a lot less of what a list wtith `n` elements takes (it's just the list overhead, without the elements).
If you still can't understand it, I'm sorry but it's probably a topic too complex for you.
The `count` approach is faster if the answer is true as the loop is also in C but there's no need for the memory allocation, however is not short circuiting.
As usual YMMV.

Comment: Ok, so like I say it uses double the memory. O(2n) is double O(n). Sorry if that's too complicated for you to understand.

Comment: FYI I spent about 10 years writing low level code in C++. So I can assure you, I know how long a pointer is.

Comment: I'm fully aware of how Pythons data model works. The point is really quite simple, and I'm surprised I have to spell this out - but then I guess that's what you get for having to deal with people who's ego is more important to them than good engineering.

Comment: You are only correct in assuming that the O(n) attributable to the additional references is << the O(n) attributable to the heap allocated space for the structs containing the referenced data if the referenced objects are >> the size of a reference itself. **This is not in general true**

Comment: @KellyBundy: good catch! indeed using `:1` is both cleaner and more correct, i'll edit the answer

Comment: Works but is not very readable.

Answer (score 5):

Check if all elements equal to the first.

`np.allclose(array, array[0])`

Comment: Needs third party module.

Comment: Also only works for a few specific types, and it's slow because of the transform of data to `numpy` array

Answer (score 4):

### Best Answer

There was a nice [Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/1254126501856870400) on the various ways to implement an all_equal() function.

Given a list input, the best submission was:

```
 t.count(t[0]) == len(t)
```

### Other Approaches

Here is are the results from the thread:

1. Have groupby() compare adjacent entries. This has an early-out for a mismatch, does not use extra memory, and it runs at C speed.

   ```
   g = itertools.groupby(s)
   next(g, True) and not next(g, False)
   ```
2. Compare two slices offset from one another by one position. This uses extra memory but runs at C speed.

   ```
   s[1:] == s[:-1]
   ```
3. Iterator version of slice comparison.  It runs at C speed and does not use extra memory; however, the *eq* calls are expensive.

   ```
   all(map(operator.eq, s, itertools.islice(s, 1, None)))
   ```
4. Compare the lowest and highest values.  This runs at C speed, doesn't use extra memory, but does cost two inequality tests per datum.

   ```
   min(s) == max(s)  # s must be non-empty
   ```
5. Build a set. This runs at C speed and uses little extra memory but requires hashability and does not have an early-out.

   ```
   len(set(t))==1.
   ```
6. At great cost, this handles NaNs and other objects with exotic equality relations.

   ```
   all(itertools.starmap(eq, itertools.product(s, repeat=2)))
   ```
7. Pull out the first element and compare all the others to it, stopping at the first mismatch.  Only disadvantage is that this doesn't run at C speed.

   ```
    it = iter(s)
    a = next(it, None)
    return all(a == b for b in it)
   ```
8. Just count the first element.  This is fast, simple, elegant. It runs at C speed, requires no additional memory, uses only equality tests, and makes only a single pass over the data.

   ```
     t.count(t[0]) == len(t)
   ```

Comment: About 12x faster alternative for the `product` check: `min(map(s.count, s)) == len(s)`

Comment: The only good answer here is `3` which still has problems because it depends on the arbitrary index manipulation

Answer (score 2):

Doubt this is the "most Pythonic", but something like:

```
>>> falseList = [1,2,3,4]
>>> trueList = [1, 1, 1]
>>> 
>>> def testList(list):
...   for item in list[1:]:
...     if item != list[0]:
...       return False
...   return True
... 
>>> testList(falseList)
False
>>> testList(trueList)
True
```

would do the trick.

Comment: Your `for` loop can be made more Pythonic into `if any(item != list[0] for item in list[1:]): return False`, with exactly the same semantics.

Comment: This really isn't great because it relies on hoisting the arbitrary value `list[0]` out of the enclosing scope

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> z = [(a[x], a[x+1]) for x in range(0, len(a)-1)]
>>> z
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]
# Replacing it with the test
>>> z = [(a[x] == a[x+1]) for x in range(0, len(a)-1)]
>>> z
[False, False, False, False, False]
>>> if False in z : Print "All elements are not equal"
```

Comment: This has some issues: Hard to understand what is going on due to somewhat arbitrary index manipulation with `range`. Also not lazy evaluated. If you wrap the creation of the pairs in a function which `yields` and the apply `any()` in place of the final step, it would be a lot better

Answer (score 2):

```
def allTheSame(i):
    j = itertools.groupby(i)
    for k in j: break
    for k in j: return False
    return True
```

Works in Python 2.4, which doesn't have "all".

Comment: `for k in j: break` is equivalent to `next(j)`. You could also have done `def allTheSame(x): return len(list(itertools.groupby(x))<2)` if you did not care about efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do:

```
all((x[i] == x[i+1] for i in range(0, len(x)-1)))
```

as `all` stops searching the iterable as soon as it finds a `True` condition.

Comment: You don't need the extra parentheses around the generator expression if it's the only argument.

Comment: so does `all()`, why not use `all(x == seq[0] for x in seq)` ? looks more pythonic and should perform the same

Comment: Reasonable, but relies on this awful arbitrary index manipulation

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Please don't break answers, at least adjust the text to the changed code.

Comment: @KellyBundy Why is it now broken? Please do edit ...

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Because the code uses `all` but the text talks about `any`. Makes no sense. Btw, someone else might've had posted the `all` solution already and this answer might've intentionally showcased `any`, consciously avoiding duplicating the other answer. If that's the case (I'm not in the mood to research it), such a change is also bad for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
reduce(and_, (x==yourList[0] for x in yourList), True)
```

It is fairly annoying that python makes you import the operators like `operator.and_`. As of python3, you will need to also import `functools.reduce`.

(You should not use this method because it will not break if it finds non-equal values, but will continue examining the entire list. It is just included here as an answer for completeness.)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding using `reduce()` with `lambda`. Here is a working code that I personally think is way nicer than some of the other answers.

```
reduce(lambda x, y: (x[1]==y, y), [2, 2, 2], (True, 2))
```

Returns a tuple where the first value is the boolean if all items are same or not.

Comment: There is a small mistake in the code as written (try `[1, 2, 2]`): it doesn't take the previous boolean value into account. This can be fixed by replacing `x[1] == y` with `x[0] and x[1] == y`.

Comment: It's not totally horrendous like some of these others - at least in principle, but I have no clue what the final part of the line is about, so I suspect it is wrong. Do you really need the arbitrary starting condition? `(True, 2)`. Also why does the initial condition have a `2` in it at all?

Answer (score 1):

Or use `diff` method of numpy:

```
import numpy as np
def allthesame(l):
    return np.all(np.diff(l)==0)
```

And to call:

```
print(allthesame([1,1,1]))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: I think `not np.any(np.diff(l))` could be a bit faster.

Comment: This depends on numpy and so will not work for the majority of types

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this one-liner

```py
from itertools import starmap, pairwise
all(starmap(eq, (pairwise(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

More versions using `itertools.groupby` that I find clearer than the original (more about that below):

```
def all_equal(iterable):
    g = groupby(iterable)
    return not any(g) or not any(g)

def all_equal(iterable):
    g = groupby(iterable)
    next(g, None)
    return not next(g, False)

def all_equal(iterable):
    g = groupby(iterable)
    return not next(g, False) or not next(g, False)
```

Here's the original from the [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) again:

```
def all_equal(iterable):
    g = groupby(iterable)
    return next(g, True) and not next(g, False)
```

Note that the `next(g, True)` is *always* [true](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) (it's either a non-empty `tuple` or `True`). That means its value doesn't matter. It's executed *purely* for advancing the `groupby` iterator. But including it in the `return` expression leads the reader into thinking that its value gets used there. Since it doesn't, I find that misleading and unnecessarily complicated. My second version above treats the `next(g, True)` as what it's actually used for, as a statement whose value we don't care about.

My third version goes a different direction and *does* use the value of the first `next(g, False)`. If there isn't even a first group at all (i.e., if the given iterable is "empty"), then that solution returns the result right away and doesn't even check whether there's a second group.

My first solution is basically the same as my third, just using `any`. Both solutions read as "All elements are equal iff ... there is no first group or there is no second group."

Benchmark results (although speed is really not my point here, clarity is, and in practice if there are many equal values, most of the time might be spent by the `groupby` itself, reducing the impact of these differences here):

```
Python 3.10.4 on my Windows laptop:

iterable = ()
 914 ns   914 ns   916 ns  use_first_any
 917 ns   925 ns   925 ns  use_first_next
1074 ns  1075 ns  1075 ns  next_as_statement
1081 ns  1083 ns  1084 ns  original

iterable = (1,)
1290 ns  1290 ns  1291 ns  next_as_statement
1303 ns  1307 ns  1307 ns  use_first_next
1306 ns  1307 ns  1309 ns  use_first_any
1318 ns  1319 ns  1320 ns  original

iterable = (1, 2)
1463 ns  1464 ns  1467 ns  use_first_any
1463 ns  1463 ns  1467 ns  next_as_statement
1477 ns  1479 ns  1481 ns  use_first_next
1487 ns  1489 ns  1492 ns  original
```

```
Python 3.10.4 on a Debian Google Compute Engine instance:

iterable = ()
 234 ns   234 ns   234 ns  use_first_any
 234 ns   235 ns   235 ns  use_first_next
 264 ns   264 ns   264 ns  next_as_statement
 265 ns   265 ns   265 ns  original

iterable = (1,)
 308 ns   308 ns   308 ns  next_as_statement
 315 ns   315 ns   315 ns  original
 316 ns   316 ns   317 ns  use_first_any
 317 ns   317 ns   317 ns  use_first_next

iterable = (1, 2)
 361 ns   361 ns   361 ns  next_as_statement
 367 ns   367 ns   367 ns  original
 384 ns   385 ns   385 ns  use_first_next
 386 ns   387 ns   387 ns  use_first_any
```

Benchmark code:

```
from timeit import timeit
from random import shuffle
from bisect import insort
from itertools import groupby

def original(iterable):
    g = groupby(iterable)
    return next(g, True) and not next(g, False)

def use_first_any(iterable):
    g = groupby(iterable)
    return not any(g) or not any(g)

def next_as_statement(iterable):
    g = groupby(iterable)
    next(g, None)
    return not next(g, False)

def use_first_next(iterable):
    g = groupby(iterable)
    return not next(g, False) or not next(g, False)

funcs = [original, use_first_any, next_as_statement, use_first_next]

for iterable in (), (1,), (1, 2):
    print(f'{iterable = }')
    times = {func: [] for func in funcs}
    for _ in range(1000):
        shuffle(funcs)
        for func in funcs:
            number = 1000
            t = timeit(lambda: func(iterable), number=number) / number
            insort(times[func], t)
    for func in sorted(funcs, key=times.get):
        print(*('%4d ns ' % round(t * 1e9) for t in times[func][:3]), func.__name__)
    print()
```

Comment: To make `all_equal` work with `pd.NA`, just [add an exception handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59543818/357313).

Comment: `groupby` is presumably going to do some form of sort first? In which case, why?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant No. Why presume that? Does its documentation somehow suggest that?

Comment: @KellyBundy How else would groupby order unordered elements. I haven't looked into detail as to what algorithm is being used, but what I do know is any work being done by groupby is unnecessary

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant It finds groups of equal ***consecutive*** values. For example, `[1,1,2,2,1,1]` are **three** groups. And the solutions shown here will only go through `1,1,2`, at which point the second group is discovered and the whole thing stops, with the result `False`. This is highly efficient, **no** unnecessary work is done.

Comment: @KellyBundy Look at this doc page and then tell me no additional work is being done. https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant No additional work is done. And I'm **very** familiar with it. I don't know what your misconception is. What additional work do you think it does? Let's go into detail, using my example `[1,1,2,2,1,1]`. The `groupby(iterable)` doesn't look at it ***at all***, only stores a pointer to it for later. Then the first `next` (or `any`) makes it look at the first `1` and it returns reporting that there's a group of `1`s. Then the second `next` makes it look at the following `1` and `2` and it reports that there's a group of `2`s. That's all. What additional work do you see there?

Comment: @KellyBundy It quite clearly creates and return a new list of references to existing objects. That is unceccessary work being done. It involves allocating heap, likely log(n) times, with log(n) copy operations of O(n) references on average.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant It doesn't create any lists. It's lazy iterators. A small constant number of objects, taking a small constant amount of memory. Just like the starmap(eq, pairwise) solution.

Comment: @KellyBundy Fine, if that is the case I agree there probably isn't any overhead from memory allocation, however being a function which executes Python byte code it is still slower than the alternative options written in C. Point being: It is still a slow solution.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Yours and all the other answers posted also execute Python byte code. This is **fast**, up to ~5.5 times faster than yours.

Comment: @KellyBundy show your performance calculations

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVLBasMwDIUddshX6FYnS0vTwhiFfUkZRt3kzJDYrq0wytiX7NLL9lH7mjlx0pTqpqenpyeh71934ndrzuefjtXy6e_uXnnbgmbybG0TQLfOeoba284dTiUERt-iK8Gh9h86UDY0WEce2fqJT8eEs25pwiJFyVfbmSgOGIZalr2RggMGarQh0c_FQ0P5LoMYDkNIDGwaSccOG1ndkmp4nuzNpaHiiTtvwFgGNCdR5xANztmt8uZWeeyPDDGuLeg4bz7T86g1JdHNvnqBAqp1UTzCA-w3lyzLVHQgQRvwaGoS23FSD6seni5RXm98nWxSQx-8jrP6I4r8gjmvDQs1WytBLT5FYi15nRcVbXerSn1BG2ARqyspDbYkZRJJAnl6h_Erpu_4Bw)

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant So, what do you think about it now?

Comment: @KellyBundy There's a few things to consider. This result is surprising, and I would be interested to understand why this is the case. I would refer back to one of my other comments made previously (may have been on this thread but perhaps not) where I said if speed is your end objective Python is the wrong choice. My objection to most of the other answers is that they are unreadable. This solution too, is unreadable, by which I mean it is not immediately obvious what it is doing by looking at it. (Which is the main point of choosing Python.)

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant It shouldn't surprise. The `groupby` iterator directly reads and compares the elements. In that other solution, `pairwise` reads the elements and creates 2-tuples of them, transmits those to `starmap`, which asks `eq` to compare them, which replies accordingly, and then `starmap` transmits the comparison results to `all`, which does its thing. That's a lot of overhead for each element. Should be *expected* to be slower. The "If you want speed, don't use Python" sentiment is inappropriate. You might want Python for what it does well, and just not want it unnecessarily slow.

Comment: @KellyBundy No, I don't agree. Readable code is more important than premature optimization which is the root of all evil. If you want it to run faster, then Python is de-facto the wrong choice.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant You truly love seeing yourself write "evil" as if that's cool, huh? That quote doesn't really apply to recipes/libraries to be used by arbitrary other people, though, for some of which optimizations might be very valuable. For most things I use I don't care how readable their code is, because I don't read it. I just use it. And I do prefer it to be fast. And no, Python is absolutely not the wrong choice for me for most of what I do. Also, you're exaggerating how unreadable things are and how readable they should be.

Comment: @KellyBundy All code is intended to be read and modified

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant If all code needs to be easily readable by everyone, we won't get anywhere :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy I would suggest that most good engineers have a solid and intuitive understanding of what good (dare I say "clean") code looks like and why one line of code is easier to understand than another. You're free to disagree and continue to write bad code, if you want.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Do you realize you're saying that after you posted the by far **worst** code of all here? The third in your answer. And the second one is painfully bad, too, and you're not even describing it correctly. With that and with all the egregious mistakes you've made, you're really in no position to judge any code. At least not any Python code. Maybe you're better at some other language.

Comment: @KellyBundy If you read the answer, you will see that I state both are bad. Are you here just to try and 1-up me or is the a website were we try to do productive things.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant I know, but the reasons you give for why they're bad aren't the actual reasons they're bad. And your reasons for the second solution aren't even correct. Not trying to "1-up", just trying to prevent you from misinforming others. Do you not remember how many false accusations you made against this answer alone?

Comment: @KellyBundy please go comment on the actual answer and raise your comments there

Answer (score 0):

```
lambda lst: reduce(lambda a,b:(b,b==a[0] and a[1]), lst, (lst[0], True))[1]
```

The next one will short short circuit:

```
all(itertools.imap(lambda i:yourlist[i]==yourlist[i+1], xrange(len(yourlist)-1)))
```

Comment: Your first code was obviously wrong: `reduce(lambda a,b:a==b, [2,2,2])` yields `False`... I edited it, but this way it's not pretty anymore

Comment: Does anyone understand how this is supposed to work? I looked at it for about a minute. The fact that I couldn't understand what it was supposed to be doing when I could read all of the other answers in a fraction of the time indicates this is not a good solution. Code smell

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Yes, I understand them :-). Pretty easy, though yes, the first one is relatively complicated (and no good).

Answer (score 0):

Can use map and lambda

```
lst = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

print all(map(lambda x: x == lst[0], lst[1:]))
```

Comment: Is comparison slower than slicing (`==` slower than `1:`)? `all(map(lambda x: x == lst[0], lst))`

Comment: This is really not great because you have a weird dependency on `lst[0]`. You are basically hoisting that value out of the enclosing scope.

Answer (score 0):

Or use diff method of numpy:

```
import numpy as np
def allthesame(l):
    return np.unique(l).shape[0]<=1
```

And to call:

```
print(allthesame([1,1,1]))
```

Output:

True

Comment: This answer is identical to an answer from U9-Forward from last year.

Comment: Good eye! I used the same structure/API, but my method uses np.unique and shape. U9's function uses np.all() and np.diff() -- I don't use either of those functions.

Comment: There are many issues with this: It depends on numpy, requires extra work to transform the data into a `numpy` array, and will only work for specific sets of types. (Numerical things)

Answer (score 0):

### The simple solution is to apply set on list

#### if all elements are identical len will be 1 else greater than 1

```py
lst = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
len_lst = len(list(set(lst)))

print(len_lst)

1


lst = [1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
len_lst = len(list(set(lst)))
print(len_lst)

2
```

Comment: How is your answer different from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23415761

Comment: This only works for hashable types. It is relatively easy to add a hash function to arbitrary types but this extra requirement isn't ideal. Also `set` is not lazy evaluated, so likely inefficient for large datasets

Answer (score 0):

They're all equal if there aren't two groups.

```py
from itertools import groupby, pairwise

def all_equal(iterable):
    return not any(pairwise(groupby(iterable)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bY8xDsIwDEX3nOKPiRQGmBCXQalIIFIaB9cR6llYusBNOAS3AdQUFjzYkuX_5He9l1FOlKfpViWsts9HYOoRxbMQpQGxL8SCI1Mt3WhRXORLHLxSBx_gUtr7c3VJfxKuS97sFN7FXipnZBK4POolpRvnd26MUoEYywIxQxsLvbZzx7rNTUMXjlm-APvvBzPLNKfF7QU)

Answer (score -1):

If you're interested in something a little more readable (but of course not as efficient,) you could try:

```
def compare_lists(list1, list2):
    if len(list1) != len(list2): # Weed out unequal length lists.
        return False
    for item in list1:
        if item not in list2:
            return False
    return True

a_list_1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'pear']
a_list_2 = ['pear', 'orange', 'grape', 'apple']

b_list_1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'pear']
b_list_2 = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear']

c_list_1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape']
c_list_2 = ['grape', 'orange']

print compare_lists(a_list_1, a_list_2) # Returns True
print compare_lists(b_list_1, b_list_2) # Returns False
print compare_lists(c_list_1, c_list_2) # Returns False
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to see if all elements in one list are identical; not if two separate lists are identical.

Comment: This is also enormously inefficient; for an input of length N it takes N^2 steps.**At the very least**, if the values are hashable, use a set for the containment tests.

Comment: I don't agree that this is "readable". It is very hard to understand what is going on here. You check that items in `list1` are in `list2` but do not do the reverse operation. So the logic is actually wrong anyway

Answer (score -1):

There is also a pure Python recursive option:

```
def checkEqual(lst):
    if len(lst)==2 :
        return lst[0]==lst[1]
    else:
        return lst[0]==lst[1] and checkEqual(lst[1:])
```

However for some reason it is in some cases two orders of magnitude slower than other options. Coming from C language mentality, I expected this to be faster, but it is not!

The other disadvantage is that there is recursion limit in Python which needs to be adjusted in this case. For example using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15241424/4999991).

Comment: Recursive solutions blow up even for modest size inputs

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant , thanks for your feedback, and I'm sorry if my answer does not meet your expectations. Please consider that this was never meant to be an optimum solution. I just added this for the completeness of the discussion. I have even admitted that this solution might be several orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: You are not the first person to do this (obviously, as you can see there are many other answers which serve no purpose other than to suggest an alternative way of doing things.) Why? What is the point of this? It just obscures the better answers by filling the answers section with pages of "spam". The point of this site is not to demonstrate every possible way of doing something but to provide (ideally just one) good solution(s). If an answer has been posted, and you think of a better solution, then of course, you should post it. But posting things which are obviously worse - why?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant I don't think we share the definition of spam, nor do we agree about the function of this website. SO's business model is based on advertisement, and the more complete the keyword pool on this page, the more visits it gets. From the user's point of view, it is not just the best solution that benefits the visitors, IMHO, but also the less optimal ones.  It induces discussion, as we see right now, and encourages critical thinking... anyway thanks for sharing your opinion, and I wish you the best.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.nunique()` to find number of unique items in a list.

```
def identical_elements(list):
    series = pd.Series(list)
    if series.nunique() == 1: identical = True
    else:  identical = False
    return identical



identical_elements(['a', 'a'])
Out[427]: True

identical_elements(['a', 'b'])
Out[428]: False
```

Comment: Yes, but `nunique` [does too much work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59543818/357313).

Comment: This also has two additional problems: Dependency on `pandas`. Extra work done to create `Series` object

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm underestimating the problem? Check the length of unique values in the list.

```py
lzt = [1,1,1,1,1,2]

if (len(set(lzt)) > 1):
    uniform = False
elif (len(set(lzt)) == 1):
    uniform = True
elif (not lzt):
    raise ValueError("List empty, get wrecked")
```

Comment: I wouldn't be afraid of empty lists… can you say that no (zero count) (non)values are different to each other?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score -1):

This was a fun one to read through and think about. Thanks everyone!
I don't think anything relying on pure count will be reliable for all cases. Also sum could work but only for numbers or length (again resulting in a count scenario).

But I do like the simplicity, so this is **what I came up with**:

```
all(i==lst[c-1] for c, i in enumerate(lst))
```

Alternatively, I do think this clever one by **@kennytm** would also work for all cases (and is probably the fastest, interestingly). So I concede that it's probably **better** than mine:

```
[lst[0]]*len(lst) == lst
```

A little bonus clever one I think would also work because set gets rid of duplicates (and clever is fun but not generally best practice for maintaining code). And I think the one by **@kennytm** would still be faster but really only relevant for large lists:

```
len(set(lst)) == 1
```

But the simplicity and cleverness of Python is one of my favorite things about the language. And thinking about it a little more, if you have to modify the list in anyway, like I actually do because I'm comparing addresses (and will remove leading/trailing spaces and convert to lower case to remove possible inconsistencies, mine would be more suited for the job). So "better" is subjective as I eluded to by using quotes when I use that word! But you could also cleanup the list beforehand.

Best and good luck!

Comment: Good catch, I glanced at the command and obviously hadn't thought it through all the way.. It splits the list and then reverses to compare (I had only saw the reverse). So it might work for all cases, I'm not sure? But I just removed it until I can test some use cases. But the logic is also hard to follow for large cases, so I'm not sure I'd use it anyways. Thanks!

Comment: `-1`. These deliberations do not add much to, for example, @ninjagecko's answer from way back in 2012: `all(x==myList[0] for x in myList)`. The top proposed solution here is similar but less performant and harder to comprehend.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest a simple pythonic solution:

```py
def all_equal_in_iterable(iterable: Iterable):
    iterable = list(iterable)
    if not iterable:
        return True
    return all(item == iterable[0] for item in iterable)
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a code with good amount of Pythonicity, and balance of simplicity and obviousness, I think, which should work also in pretty old Python versions.

```
def all_eq(lst):
    for idx, itm in enumerate(lst):
        if not idx:   # == 0
            prev = itm
        if itm != prev:
            return False
        prev = itm
    return True
```

Comment: (Almost useful, but lacks a docstring: While the name is mnemonic, I like to check the hover in my IDE, e.g.: `all_eq([])`?)

Comment: @greybeard sorry, it's not an official package

Comment: (You write "undocumented" code? Didn't work for me.)

Answer (score -2):

A functional solution, which results in a clean code:

**Advantages:**

- Lazy evaluated
- No side effects, does not depend on side effects from enclosing scope (eg does not pull random values like `input[0]` out of the enclosing scope - this is fragile for obvious reasons)
- Only requires `operator.eq` to be defined for input types. Does not require `__hash__`
- Functional style (no for loops!)
- It works for edge cases, for example empty list or list with a single element

```
input_list [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

import operator
from itertools import pairwise
from itertools import starmap

def all_items_in_list_are_equal(l: list) -> bool:

    all_items_are_equal = \
        all(
            starmap(
                operator.eq,
                pairwise(l)
            )
        )

    return all_items_are_equal
```

It works by producing a pairwise iterator `pairwise(l)` which returns pairs of adjacent elements in the list `l` as a tuple.

The tuple is expanded into pairs of arguments by `starmap`.

- `starmap` is to `map` what `function(*args)` is to `function(a, b, c, ...)`

`operator.eq` expects two arguments, so a single argument of type `pair` will not do. We use `starmap` to apply `operator.eq` to every pair of values yield by the iterator, effectively by expanding the tuple into a pair of individual arguments.

Finally, `all` effectively applies a lambda function to check that all elements are `True`.

Note: This answer came from a separate question I asked about achieving the same objective as in the original question here, but in a functional style. I asked this question after reading through the entire history of answers here.

Most of the other answers have problems, for example:

- edge cases
- poor performance due to eager evaluation
- irregular dependencies, in other words:
- fragile code which is likely to break due to different lines of code depending on each other in weird ways
- the use of `for` loops, which of course are evil

---

There is another solution which avoids the overhead of `starmap`, `pairwise` at the cost of maintaining and iterating over a pair of iterators.

The problem with this is it involves index manipulation which is an easy way to produce unmaintainable code, and edge cases/bugs. (eg: Will this work with a list of length 0?)

It also isn't especially readable because it forces you to think about index operations.

```
input_list [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

import operator

def all_items_in_list_are_equal(l: list) -> bool:

    all_items_are_equal = \
        all(
            map(
                operator.eq,
                l[1:],
                l[:-1]
            )
        )

    return all_items_are_equal
```

---

If you were wondering if building a custom iterator provides a good solution, the answer is unfortunately "no" because the resulting code is pretty slow. (Even taking into account an optimization which removes the need for a branch statement in the `__next__` function.)

```
class EqualPairwiseIterator():

    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.iterable = iterable
        self.iterator = iter(iterable)
        self.previous_value = None
        if len(iterable) < 1:
            raise ValueError(f'EqualPairwiseIterator does not work with lists of length 0')

    def __iter__(self):
        try:
            self.previous_value = next(self.iterator) # will raise StopException when out of range
        except StopException as stop_exception:
            raise ValueError(f'EqualPairwiseIterator does not work with lists of length 0')
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        
        next_value = next(self.iterator) # will raise StopException when out of range
        op_value = operator.eq(next_value, self.previous_value)
        self.previous_value = next_value
        return op_value 

# useage:
iterable = [...]
all(EqualPairwiseIterator(iterable))
```

Comment: *"I asked this question after reading through the entire history of answers here."* - Did you really? This solution was [already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71864785) here, but your question claims *"none of these take a functional approach"* and now your answer claims this same solution **is** functional.

Comment: @KellyBundy I must have missed that answer when I was scrolling through. There were a lot to inspect, and the majority of them most of them are just people suggesting "alternative ways of doing the same thing which have not yet been suggested". The point of this site is not to collect all possible ways of doing something, but to provide good solutions. Most of the answers here are not good. Most of them are pretty bad. I apologize if I missed one as I didn't realize there were two pages of answers. I have not looked at anything on page 2.