# Running functions from a list issue

Tags: python

I am wondering how to run functions from a list, and calling them using the random module, but I can't seem to get it to work can anyone help? Here is an example below.

```
import random
def word1():
       print "Hello"
def word2():
       print "Hello again"

wordFunctList = [word1, word2]

def run():
       printWord = random.randint(1, len(wordFunctList))-1
       wordFunctList[printWord]
       run()
run()
```

So I wanted to do this in an infinite loop, but all I get for output is

```
Hello
Hello again
```

Then the program just doesn't do anything else? Can anyone help me? Btw, I am using the app pythonista. Also I am a programming NOOB. I just recently started with python.

The whole reason I am asking this question is because I am making a text based world generator, and I want to define functions for biomes, then randomly call them from a list while the world is generating.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem which is not reproducible.

Comment: I am sure you wouldn't have got the output you mentioned in the question, since you didn't invoke the functions and it is already executed infinitely, and causes stackoverflow

Comment: Well this in my original program I used time.sleep to prevent instantaneous stack overflow

Comment: You know, it might be a bug with pythonista...

Comment: I will try to re-create this on my raspberry pi.

Comment: I just tried it on pythonista again, and I got the same output I mentioned, even with the new suggested method below. I am really starting to think that it is a bug with pythonista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
import random

def word1():
    print "Hello"

def word2():
    print "Hello again"

wordFunctList = [word1,  word2]

def run():
    # Infinite loop, instead of recursion
    while True:
        # Choose the function randomly from the list and call it
        random.choice(wordFunctList)()

run()
```

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6809586/2301450). It explains why you should avoid tail recursion and use infinite loop instead.

Explanation on `random.choice(wordFunctList)()`:

`wordFunctList` is a list with function objects:

```
>>> print wordFunctList
[<function word1 at 0x7fcb1f453c08>, <function word2 at 0x7fcb1f453c80>]
```

`random.choice(wordFunctList)` chooses the function and returns it:

```
>>> random.choice(wordFunctList)
<function word2 at 0x7f9ce040dc80>
```

`random.choice(wordFunctList)()` calls the returned function:

```
>>> print random.choice(wordFunctList)()
Hello again # Outputs during the function call
None        # Returned value
```

With extra parentheses (`random.choice(wordFunctList)()()`), you were calling the returned value of the function, that is `None`, but `None` is not callable and that's why you were getting the error.

Comment: How would I go about choosing the function and calling it, in the same way? Or another way? Because if I am calling the function wrong, I get a TypeError: object not callable

Comment: @user3487713 if there're only functions in your list, then you can't get `object not callable` error

Comment: The error also said something about a 'NoneType' don't know if that changes anything...

Comment: Maybe it's because I accidentally added extra parentheses at the end. And it now seems to be working...

Comment: Well, the code is working, so I can now focus on the world generator I am making.

Comment: @user3487713 your functions return `None`, `random.choice(wordFunctList)` is a function object, `random.choice(wordFunctList)()` is a NoneType object, calling NoneType object causes error. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Sorry if this frustrates anyone, but I can do some beginner programming, but the vocabulary used when describing it is complicated for me.

Comment: @user3487713 updated the answer with extra explanation. You should also accept the answer if you find it helpful **and** comprehensive.

Comment: I get it now, I think I just stayed up too late to read it clearly, otherwise, it does make a lot more sense now, thanks for the input on the problem!

Comment: How do I accept answers? I just joined stackexchange about 50 minutes ago? I am also running this on a mobile phone.