# python reduce to check if all elements are equal

Tags: python, reduce

Suppose `a = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`
`reduce(lambda x,y: x==y, a)` returns `True`

But if `a = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`
`reduce(lambda x,y: x==y, a)` returns `False`

Why in the second case, the outcome is `False`?

please help

thanks

Comment: If you not insist on `reduce`, there's Q: [Check if all elements in a list are identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844801/check-if-all-elements-in-a-list-are-identical)

Answer (score 11):

Try this instead, it works for lists of any size:

```
all(e == a[0] for e in a)
```

Notice that your proposed solution using `reduce` doesn't work for more than two items, as the accumulated value after the first comparison is `True`, and you'd be comparing `True` against each of the elements from that point on, and obviously that's not going to work.

Comment: sure. actually I am doing the simpler `a[1:] == a[:-1]`  it works, but my question is why `reduce` produces unexpected result as shown in my question?

Comment: @Jack no, that's not what you're doing. See my edited answer.

Comment: Nice, but not best for e.g. one-time iterables.

Answer (score 5):

You are **not** reducing the lists.  The return value of your lambda is `True` or `False`, which is then used as input parameters to further calls to the same lambda function.  So you end up comparing a boolean with a list.  Therefore, the reducing function should return the same type as it input parameters.

You were probably looking for what other answers proposed instead: use `all()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can still use reduce! Check out this magic:

```
bool(reduce(lambda x,y: (x==y)*x, a))
```

Since the return value of the lambda for `x==y` is True or False, that can be multiplied by the input and then used in the next comparison because `True*[1,2,3]` is `[1,2,3]`. It also works for strings, `True*"MyString"` is `"MyString"`.

Try it. However, this method will not work for a list of zeros.

Comment: Cute. Dangerous, but cute.

Answer (score 2):

Because first time reduce compare [1,2,3] == [1, 2, 3] and it's true
next time it compare True and [1,2,3] and it's false.

> > > help(reduce)

```
Help on built-in function reduce in module __builtin__:

reduce(...)
    reduce(function, sequence[, initial]) -> value

    Apply a function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of a sequence,
    from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value.
    For example, reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) calculates
    ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5).
```

Answer (score 1):

`a = [range(1, 4), range(1, 4), range(1, 4)]`

To evaluate `reduce(operator.eq, a)` the `reduce` function will first evaluate the function `operator.eq` on the first two elements of `a` to obtain `True`.  Then it will call `operator.eq` again with `True` and `range(1, 4)` as the two arguments, and obtain `False` which is the final result of `reduce`.

Perhaps you are wanting:

```
from functools import partial
import operator
allequal = reduce(partial(operator.eq, a[0]), a[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why in the second case, the outcome is False

Because `reduce(lambda x, y: x == y, (a, b, c, d))` does not mean `(a == b) and (b == c) and (c == d)`; it means `(((a == b) == c) == d)`. `a == b` will produce either `True` or `False`, which then gets compared to `c`.