# How to check if every element in list are equal?

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [check if all elements in a list are identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844801/check-if-all-elements-in-a-list-are-identical)

I want to check if all of the elements of a list are equal. I couldn't do this with:

```
if all (x == x for x in (a, b, c, d)):
    ...
```

Is there very minimalistic and elegant way to do this in Python?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844801/check-if-all-elements-in-a-list-are-identical

Comment: Are you not just comparing each element to itself here? When would an element not be equal to itself?

Comment: @Eric: Good call, didn't remember anymore whether `NaN` exists in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have only hashable elements in your list you can use a [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html%20set).

For example if your list is named `lst` you can do:

```
if (len(set(lst)) <= 1):
    ....
```

The set will eliminate all the duplicates in your list, so if the length of the set is *1* it means that all the elements are the same.

Comment: This will fail if the items in the list aren't hashable.

Comment: True, I don't know why but I assumed he was going to compare numbers, I'll edit the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
all(x == items[0] for x in items)
```

this is what you're looking for.

Otherwise you would be comparing every value to itself `x==x` as opposed to every value to the first value.

Answer (score -1):

```
first = my_list[0]
print all(x==first for x in my_list[1:])
```

should work

more elegant maybe ... (I dont really think so...)

```
>>> if reduce(lambda item0,item1:item0 if item0==item1 else False,my_list) is not False:
...    print "OK ALL THE SAME!"
...
OK ALL THE SAME!
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this works?

Comment: reduce applies a function to every pair of elements in the list shrinking it until there is only a scalar value left .. bah reduce didnt work ... ill see if i can get a version working with reduce

Answer (score -3):

answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844801/check-if-all-elements-in-a-list-are-identical) , with performance benchmark

my favorite : `lst[1:] == lst[:-1]`

Comment: Then please vote to close / flag this question as duplicate and don't copy answers.