# Check if list of numpy arrays are equal

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of numpy arrays, and want to check if all the arrays are equal. What is the quickest way of doing this?

I am aware of the numpy.array_equal function (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html), however as far as I am aware this only applies to two arrays and I want to check N arrays against each other.

I also found this answer to test all elements in a list: [check if all elements in a list are identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844801/check-if-all-elements-in-a-list-are-identical).
However, when I try each method in the accepted answer I get an exception (ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all())

Thanks,

Comment: Are your arrays integer or float?  There are lots of questions about that `ValueError`.  Look at a few of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply [adapt a general iterator method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3844832/4686625) for your array comparison

```
def all_equal(iterator):
  try:
     iterator = iter(iterator)
     first = next(iterator)
     return all(np.array_equal(first, rest) for rest in iterator)
  except StopIteration:
     return True
```

If this is not working, it means that your arrays are *not* equal.

*Demo*:

```
>>> i = [np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([1,2,3])]
>>> print(all_equal(i))
True
>>> j = [np.array([1,2,4]),np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([1,2,3])]
>>> print(all_equal(j))
False
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.array_equal()` in a list comprehension to compare each array to the first one:

```
all([np.array_equal(list_of_arrays[0], arr) for arr in list_of_arrays])
```

Answer (score 1):

If your arrays are of equal size, this solution using [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) (disclaimer: I am its author) should work and be very efficient:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.all_unique(list_of_arrays)
```

Answer (score 0):

@jtr's answer is great, but I would like to suggest a slightly different alternative.

First of all, I think using `array_equal` is not a great idea, because you could have two arrays of floats and maybe you can end up having very small differences that you are willing to tolerate, but `array_equal` returns `True` if and only if the two arrays have the same shape and exact same elements. So let's use [`allclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html#numpy.allclose) instead, which allows to select the absolute and relative tolerances that meet your needs.

Then, I would use the built-in `zip` function, which makes the code more elegant.

Here is the code:

```py
all([np.allclose(array, array_expected), for array, array_expected in zip(array_list, array_list_expected)])
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can use the function unique.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html#numpy.unique

if all sub-arrays in the array is the same, it should return only one item.

Here's better described how to use it.

[Find unique rows in numpy.array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970982/find-unique-rows-in-numpy-array)