# How to type-check usage of next() with groupby result using mypy?

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying out mypy for some utils functions in my project, but I'm having trouble with this function that combines groupby and next.

This is the function code:

```
from itertools import groupby
from typing import Iterable, Any


def all_same(iterable: Iterable[Any]) -> bool:
    """Return True if all elements in iterable are equal
    >>> all_same([3, 3, 3])
    True
    >>> all_same([3, 3, 1])
    False
    >>> all_same([])
    True
    >>> all_same(['a', 'a'])
    True
    """
    g = groupby(iterable)
    return bool(next(g, True)) and not bool(next(g, False))
```

I keep getting this error about it not being able to infer the `type argument 1 of "next"`:

```
$ mypy testing.py 
testing.py: note: In function "all_same":
testing.py:17: error: Cannot infer type argument 1 of "next"
```

I figure it means it can't infer the type of `g` here, right?

I'm having trouble to understand if this a problem in my type annotations or in type annotations for `groupby`.

For reference, this is [the type annotation for `groupby`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/itertools.pyi#L36):

```
@overload
def groupby(iterable: Iterable[_T]) -> Iterator[Tuple[_T, Iterator[_T]]]: ...
```

So this means, "groupby takes an iterable of type T, and returns an iterator of tuples containing two items: (one item of type T, an iterator of the objects of type T)".
Looks good to me, but then mypy should be able to infer the first argument of `next` as `Iterator[Tuple[Any, Iterator[Any]]]`, right?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is due to the [type annotation for `next`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/builtins.pyi#L692). The `next` function is defined to have the following type signature:

```
@overload
def next(i: Iterator[_T]) -> _T: ...
@overload
def next(i: Iterator[_T], default: _T) -> _T: ...
```

Basically, mypy expects the type of the default value to be the same as the contents of whatever you have within the iterator.

However, `g` is going to have the type `Iterator[Tuple[Any, Iterator[Any]]]`, and `Tuple[Any, Iterator[Any]]` isn't the same type as `bool`.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure what the best way to repair your algorithm to typecheck is going to be, since the given type signature for `next` seems pretty reasonable to me + seems unlikely to be changed (though you could file an issue if you want to argue in favor for this change?). Perhaps the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3844801/646543) might be useful?

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't make sense to change my algorithm because of gradual typing though, the algorithm is sound.

Comment: This is still weird to me, because the error is about failing to infer the type.

Comment: @elias - Well, the thing is that according to mypy, your algorithm _isn't_ sound -- your code, for better or for worse, doesn't respect the type signature of `next`. The reason why mypy is complaining about failing to infer the type basically stems from this issue -- it's trying to reconcile the mismatch, and fails with that particular error message. But yeah, the fact that mypy is reporting _this_ particular error instead of a "your types don't match" error is most likely a bug.

Comment: well, I refuse to change the algorithm because of `next` type annotation, haha!
I got it from Raymond Hettinger (Python core developer) and it's a pretty good one. :)
Thanks for digging this to the end!