# How to specify types for itertools groupby?

Tags: python-3.x, python-itertools, python-typing

I've a list of string to be operated upon. And the return type is something like group type consisting of int as a key and a list of string as value.

**What i've tried?**

```py
from typing import List, Dict, Iterator

from itertools import groupby

def group_names(names: List[str]) -> Dict[int, list]:
    group_iter: Iterator[int, Iterator[list]]  = groupby(sorted(names,key=len), lambda x: len(x)) # -> Having an issue here
    return {k: list(v) for k, v in group_iter}
```

It works fine i type it as a Iterator consisting of Any type.

```py
group_iter: Iterator[Any]  = groupby(sorted(names,key=len), lambda x: len(x))
```

But i want to specify type for group key as well as a items ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refering to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090105/how-to-type-check-usage-of-next-with-groupby-result-using-mypy) i noticed that the return type of group by is:

`Iterable[Tuple[<key_type>, Iterable[<item_type>]]]`

So, the type in my case would be:

```py
group_iter: Iterator[Tuple[int, Iterable[str]]]  = groupby(sorted(names,key=len), lambda x: len(x))
```