# How to check if diagonal in matrix is equal

Tags: python

I want to make a tic tac toe game.

I'm having trouble with the diagonal.

I've managed to find a way to check if a column or row is equal with a for loop.

I need a way to check if a diagonal is equal for every move made to see if someone won.

Comment: Please see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is the format of your data? How are you checking for columns and rows? I don't think you only expect a theoretical solution?

Comment: send some code and how is your data format (panda, list, list of list, numpy array ...) ?

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: if you map fields to numbers and they have logic, like 1,5,9 has step 4; 3,5,7 diagonal has step 2 ... think of it; there are many other ways of doing it and with little googling (means using google.com search engine) you could find examples because this is typical homework :)

Answer (score 1):

Wellcome to StackOverFlow!

I recommend to use the [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) package.

```
x = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
x =
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
di = np.diag(x)

di
array([0, 4, 8])
```

now we need a [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844801/check-if-all-elements-in-a-list-are-identical) function for a list:

```
def checkEqual(lst):
   return lst[1:] == lst[:-1]
```

after you can check the list if it is "equal":

```
checkEqual(di)
```