# Python StopIteration in generator comprehension

Tags: python, generator, stopiteration

Python 3.6

Trying to write a function that returns the common string in a list of strings. Eg.

```
>>>find_common_string(*['test 1', 'test 2', 'test 3'])
```

would return

```
>>>'test '
```

I tried to prevent it from matching any other strings after the first `False` returned by `equality(iterator)` with a `StopIteration` in the generator expression

Can this be done? I get:  `#comparing a few long strings`

```
TypeError: sequence item 130: expected str instance, type found
```

This is the code:

```
def equality(iterator):
    iterator = iter(iterator)
    try:
        first = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        return True
    return all(first == rest for rest in iterator)

def find_common_string(*strings):
    result = zip(*strings)      
    result = (i[0] if equality(i) else StopIteration for i in result)
    return ''.join(result) #I tried to use this ^
```

References:
[check if all elements in a list are identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844801/check-if-all-elements-in-a-list-are-identical)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have your generator keep returning items until a condition is no longer met, you can use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile). Your problem will need a slight modification:

```
import itertools

def find_common_string(*strings): 
    result = itertools.takewhile(lambda x: equality(x), [i for i in zip(*strings)])
    return ''.join((i[0] for i in result))
```

Comment: Sweet! Did not know about that, magic. Thanks mate! -- prettier than my idea :)

Comment: @JamesSchinner use this `result = itertools.takewhile(lambda x: len(set(x)) == 1, [i for i in zip(*strings)])` and you can get rid of your other function.

Comment: One day I might think of that myself... that's a great idea! `len(set(x)) == 1`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`StopIteration` is a type

```
>>> print(type(StopIteration))
<class 'type'>
```

so if you return it this way - you only return type, but not a raised exception.

One of the ways - use `itertools.takewhile` - it stops on first non-matching element.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I see that I was returning the `StopIteration`, makes sense