# I have to make a Yahtzee game in Python. Everything else works but I cannot get the Three of a kind to work

Tags: python

Most of my code works perfectly, the only one I cannot figure out is three of a kind. If three of the same number appears it adds together to get the score. Here is that section of code as I have it right now.

```
def threeOfOne(dicelst):
    total = 0
    for die in dicelst:
        if dicelst[0] == dicelst[1:3]:
            total += die
        elif dicelst[1] == dicelst[2:5]:
            total += die
        else:
            total = 0
        return total
```

I feel like I am missing something very simple but I can't get it to work it always shows zero.

Comment: You're comparing a single value against a list!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844801/check-if-all-elements-in-a-list-are-identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function, you are checking if a single value is equivalent to a list!

```
>>> dicelst = [1,3,5,4,2]
>>> dicelst[0]
1
>>> dicelst[1:3]
[3, 5]
```

Try checking the `count` of each die in the list

```
def threeOfOne(dicelst):
    for die in dicelst:
       if dicelst.count(die) >= 3:  # only if there are at least three matches
           return die * dicelst.count(die)
    return 0
```

Here is an expression which I believe solves your problem

```
def threeOfOne(dicelst):
    return sum(x for x in dicelst if dicelst.count(x) >= 3)
```

This generates all the values in dicelst which appear at least three times

- `(x for x in y)` generator expression which iterates over y
- `dicelst.count(x)` counts the number of times x appears in dicelst
- `sum(iterable)` add everything in the contained list (or other iterable)

If you require exactly three of a kind, just check if the count == 3