# How to implement a Loop statement

Tags: python

I made a simple Yahtzee game in as few of lines as I could think. Currently, the user must press Enter (with any value) to continue. I would like to use a loop statement so that the dice continue to roll until Yahtzee (all rolled numbers are the same). I would also like a 10 second timer. What is the best way to add a loop statement to this code? P.S. This is not homework, I wanted to make this game for my Yahtzee nights. My daughter wakes easil...haha

```
import random

while True:
    dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice3 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice4 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice5 = random.randint(1,6)
    numbers = (dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5)
    sum1 = sum(numbers)
    if  sum1 == ("5" or "10" or "15" or "20" or "25"):
        print("Winner, winner, chicken dinner!", dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5)
    else:
        print("Your rolls are: ", dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5)
    input("Press return key to roll again.")
```

**EDIT: This is my final product. Thank you for all the help guys!!**

```
import random
import time
input("Press return key to roll.")
for x in range(0,10000):
    numbers = [random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(5)]
    if all(x == numbers[0] for x in numbers):
        print("Winner, winner, chicken dinner!", numbers)
        input("Press return key to play again.")

    else:
        print("Your rolls are: ", numbers)        
        print("Next roll in one second.")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: `sum1 == ("5" or ...)` condition is true only when `sum1` is `'5'`(string). What you need is `sum1 in (5, 10, ...)`. `sum1` is integer and you need to test with integer (`5` not same as `'5'`).

Comment: You have a loop (`while True:`). Add a line where you compare if all numbers are the same. If this is true `break` out of the loop. Replace `input` with a call to [`time.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep).

Comment: And of course it would be easier to drop those numbered variables `dice1`, `dice2` and so on. Just create a list: `numbers = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(5)]`.

Comment: @Matthias Thank you! That shortend my code by a lot ha ha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to check if all the dice numbers are the same it is as simple as.

```
allDice = [dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5] #List of dice variables
if all(x == allDice[0] for x in allDice): # If all dice are the same
    print("Yahtzee")
    break # Break out of while loop
```

The most simple way of having a "timer" could be adding a `time.sleep()`. You have to `import time` otherwise it won't work.

So replace
`input("Press return key to roll again.")`
with
`time.sleep(10)`

This means every 10 seconds the dice will roll until all dice are the same number, if they are then it prints Yahtzee and stops the loop.

Comment: Your solution works only for a value of `1`. A simple solution for every number would be `if len(set(values)) == 1:`.

Comment: Why `x==1`? Dice can have values from 1 to 6.

Comment: Sorry, I put that in to test and forgot to change to list value.

Comment: Change that to `all(x == allDice[0] for x in allDice[1:])`.

Comment: I just got to work and will test this when I get home. Thank you!

Comment: I shut my door and set my computer up. This work perfectly! Is there a way to only allow it to loop a certain number of times. Like it will only loop 100 times?

Comment: Yes, the best option for this is a for loop, which would do the loop 100 times. So you can change the `while True:` to `for x in range(0,100):`

Comment: You rock! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `while True:...` with a `while boolean_variable: ...` and set the value of that `boolean_variable` to `True` before the `while` loop and to `False` when you achieved Yahtzee => in the `if` condition.

What do you mean by 10 second timer, however? A sleep time of ten seconds can be implemented by a `time.sleep(10)` at the end of the inner `while` loop.

**EDIT `boolean_variable` EXAMPLE**

```
import time
...
not_yahtzee = True
while not_yathzee:
    ....
    if sum == 5 or sum == 10 or ... :
        ...
        not_yahtzee = False
    else:
        ...
        time.sleep(10)
```

The `...` represent the code you already have. As commented on your question, the `if` condition should look more like this one. [There are other ways on how to check all the elements in a list are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844801/check-if-all-elements-in-a-list-are-identical).

Comment: I'm still new to this. How do I use the boolean_variable?