# Deleting an entire list from list of lists

Tags: python, list, data-structures

I have a list of lists as follows :

```
g = [
    ["a","?","?","?","?","?","?"],
    ["?","b","?","?","?","?","?"],
    ["?","?","?","?","?","?","?"]
]
```

I want to iterate through this list and delete the list which contains all "?", which is the last list in this list of lists. I've tried pop() , del and several other operation but nothing seems to be working so far.

Here's what I've written for this part :

```
for x in g:
    if x.count("?") == 6:
        g.pop(g.index(x))
```

It doesn't remove the list but removes one "?" from the last list. Can anyone please guide me here.

Comment: I think `x.pop(g.index(x))` should be `g.pop(g.index(x))` - `g` is your list of lists, `x` is one of the lists of characters.

Comment: Also consider 6 versus 7.

Comment: Sorry my bad, that's  actually g.pop(g.index(x)), typo error. Corrected it now, would appreciate your response on this.

Comment: Just use a list comp to create a new list: `[l for l in x if any(el != "?" for el in l)]`

Comment: Try changing your test to `if all(c=='?' for c in x):`, more robust over time than testing against a number of entries.

Comment: The problem with `pop`ing in-place as you iterate is that you'll be skipping the next item in the list; how is this? Consider, for instance, that the current iteration is at index 0, and the `if` condition turns out to be `true`, that means you `pop` the item at that index 0, where will the iteration be standing??? The element at index 1 will now be the new index 0; if that's so, since the next iteration will be at index 1, which is, after the `pop` the element that was at index 2 before the `pop`, the element at index 0 after the pop will not be checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should leverage `set` here:

```
In [152]: X = [["a","?","?","?","?","?","?"],["?","b","?","?","?","?","?"],["?","?","?","?","?","?","?"]]

In [153]: [l for l in X if set(l) != {"?"}]
Out[153]: [['a', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], ['?', 'b', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?']]
```

`set(l)` gets the unique values of the list and makes a `set` out of it, comparing the resulting set with `{"?"}` would suffice as you want to drop the list with all `?`s.

Answer (score 2):

Try this list comprehension:

```
X = [["a","?","?","?","?","?","?"],["?","b","?","?","?","?","?"],["?","?","?","?","?","?","?"]]

print([l for l in X if l.count("?") == len(l)])
```

Output:

```
[['a', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], ['?', 'b', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?']]
```

As an added bonus, it is 2x faster than @heemayl's answer.

Comment: Why is this 2x faster? `count()` and `set()` should have the same complexity. For speed, `any` or `all` would be the fastest (because of short circuiting)

Comment: @pault `count` has an efficient C implementation, and `len` is stored internally, making this method quite fast. Using `timeit` trials, this method is consistently faster. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3844948 for more details.

Answer (score 1):

May be this would help!

```
[x for i,x in enumerate(X) if ''.join(x).replace('?','')]
```

## output:

```
[['a', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], ['?', 'b', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?']]
```

Answer (score 1):

In case list comprehensions are not very clear as in the answers you have received, an alternative can have this form;

```
l = [['a', '?'], ['?', '?']]

result = []
for i in l:
    if ('?' in i) and (set(i) == {'?'}):
        continue
    result.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use Lists comprehensions to solve this -

```
all([True, True, True)] 
   True
all(True, True, False)
   False
```

Thus we compare each element of sub-lists to `'?'` and in case they are `'?'`, then we return `True` and finally apply `all()` function to the sub-lists.

```
g_out = [i for i in g if all([j=='?' for j in i]) == False]
print(g_out)
    [['a', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], ['?', 'b', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `filter` with `lambda` functions as well:

```
func = lambda x: x.count("?") != len(x)
new_g = list(filter(func, g))
```