# I want to write a function that returns True if all items in a list are equal

Tags: python, python-3.x, reduce

I want to evaluate all items in a list (items will be integers, values from 1 to 16) and I want the function to return true if all items are the same regardless of their value.

This is the function I have written:

`int_positions = [1,1,1,1]` -  this returns true
`int_positions = [2,2,2,2]` this returns false although it should return true as all items are the same

```
reduce(lambda a,b: a==b, int_positions)  

>>> var2 = [2,2,2,2]  
>>> reduce(lambda a,b: a==b,var2)  
False
```

Comment: Do you have to use lambda?

Comment: Yes, this will be a function that will be used only once. so i thought using a lambda function would make sense

Comment: In terms of performance, I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39905386/10157759) in the other post is the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the list of integers to a set and check if the length of the set is 1:

```
def is_same(lst):
    return len(set(lst)) == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
>>> item = int_positions[0]
>>> all(e == item for item in int_positions)
```

Basically, what you are doing is getting the first item, and then comparing this value with every element in the item using `all` function. This function returns `True` if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty).

Comment: It's better like this: def allsame (seq): i = iter(seq); e = i.next(); return (all(x==e for x in i)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

```
result = int_positions == [int_positions[0]] * len(int_positions)
```