# How to identify identical elements in a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I have a tuple with the following structure

```
#list of tuples
[('Persons', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 11, 11, 31, 0, 160000), datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 11, 12, 8, 25, 320000))]
#[0] index position
('Persons', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 11, 11, 31, 0, 160000), datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 11, 12, 8, 25, 320000))
```

Now how to identify whether `datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 11, 11, 31, 0, 160000)` and `datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 11, 12, 8, 25, 320000)` are identical or not (equality test)?

***I have answered the question***

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if all elements in a list are identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844801/check-if-all-elements-in-a-list-are-identical)

Answer (score 2):

`Datetime` supports equality tests.

```
a = [('Persons', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 11, 11, 31, 0, 160000), datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 11, 12, 8, 25, 320000))]
print(a[0][0] == a[0][1])  # False
```

Comment: Hi @Will Derriman ...It is showing false for even equal elements. For example, it is showing false for `[('brand_approvals', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 6, 18, 5, 9, 600000), datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 6, 18, 5, 9, 600000))]`. Thank you for answering :)

Comment: Hi @KrisT, very interesting. 

`dt1 = datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 11, 11, 31, 0, 160000)
dt3 = datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 11, 11, 31, 0, 160000) 
dt2 = datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 11, 12, 8, 25, 320000)
print(dt1 == dt2)  # False
print(dt1 == dt3)  # True`

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me to identify identical tuple index items.

```
       #list of tuples
        row = [('Persons', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 11, 11, 31, 0, 160000), datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 11, 12, 8, 25, 320000))]   


        #converting list to a tuple
        listT = row[0]
        listT = ('Persons', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 11, 11, 31, 0, 160000), datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 11, 12, 8, 25, 320000))

        #comparing tuple index positions
        if listT[1] == listT[2]:
            print('both are equal')
        else:
            print('they are not equal')
```