# 2d array if the elements are same

Tags: python

I have list of lists looks like

```
a=[[1,2],[2,1],[2,3]]
```

I would like to check if the fırst elements of sublist are same, if they are same I would like to put them a new list.

I tried

```
for x in a:
    for y in x:
        if y in x:
```

I could not find what to write after that.
My output is that new lists like

```
a1=[[2,3,1],[1,2]]
```

Thank you

Comment: Why are you looping through `x`? You only care about the first elements of the sublists, not all the elements.

Comment: What output do you expect? Can you work through how to get it by hand?

Comment: Use a list comprehension to get the first element of each sublist. Then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844801/check-if-all-elements-in-a-list-are-identical for how to test if all of them are the same.

Comment: Can you explain how that output relates to the input? I don't see the pattern.

Comment: I added the expected output. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see it. `[2, 3, 1]` comes from `[2, 1] and `[2, 3]` because they both begin with `2`.

Comment: `if y in x:` will always be true, since `y` is looping through the elements of `x`. You're comparing elements of the same sublist, not different sublists.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go for dictionary.

```
a = [[1,2],[2,1],[2,3]]

d = {}
for x in a:
    head = x[0]
    if head in d.keys():
        d[head].extend(x[1:])
    else:
        d[head] = x[1:]

result = [[key] + d[key] for key in d.keys()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a=[[2,2],[2,1],[2,3]]
myList=[x[0] for x in a]
print(all(y==myList[0] for y in myList))
```

If same then True else False