# Check if Values from List of Dictionaries are Unique Without Keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary like the one bellow:

```py
d = {
    "00068693": [
        {"LABP": "022012"},
        {"LAOS": "022012"},
        {"LAOS": "022012"},
        {"LAOS": "022012"},
        {"LAOS": "022012"},
        {"LAOS": "022012"},
        {"LABC": "022012"},
        {"LACL": "022012"},
        {"LACL": "022012"},
        {"LACL": "022012"},
        {"LACL": "349309"},
    ],
    "00084737": [
        {"LABP": "022012"},
        {"LAOS": "022012"},
        {"LABC": "022012"},
        {"LACL": "022012"},
    ]
}
```

The goal of my code is to check if an ID (ex.: `"00068693"`) has a unique code (ex.: `"022012"`) on all files (ex.: `"LAOS"`).

So the output for this example should be:

```
ID: "00068693" has different codes.
ID: "00084737" has a unique code.
```

But, how do I check this?

Because I don't know what files the ID has, so I can't access through each key of the list.

I'm not trying to compare the elements, just the values for each dict, but each one of them are on a different list index and I don't know the keys.

Comment: `dict.values()` will return a sequence of all the values in a dictionary, so you don't need to know the keys.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if all elements in a list are identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844801/check-if-all-elements-in-a-list-are-identical). Which list? `[list(d.values())[0] for d in files]`

Comment: Do all the nested dictionaries have just one element? That will simplify getting a list of all the values.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but it returns a list like this:

[
    dict_values(["022012"]),
    dict_values(["022012"]),
    dict_values(["022012"]),
    dict_values(["022012"]),
    dict_values(["022012"]),
    dict_values(["022012"]),
    dict_values(["022012"]),
    dict_values(["022012"]),
    dict_values(["022012"]),
    dict_values(["022012"]),
    dict_values(["022012"]),
    dict_values(["349309"]),
]

Comment: `[d.values()[0] for d in list_of_dicts]`

Comment: @Barmar `'dict_values' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @Barmar yes, all the cases follow the exact model of the question.

Comment: Are you getting this structure from somewhere or generating it? It would make more sense to be a single dict instead of a list of dicts of single values. If it were `"00068693": {"LABP": "022012", "LAOS": "022012", ...}` It would be as simple as `codes = d.values()`

Comment: Thank you, @Tomerikoo, I'll make the changes and test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [Check if all elements in a list are identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844801/check-if-all-elements-in-a-list-are-identical). The question is which list? Well, you need to construct a list of the codes of all files. We don't really care what the files are, just their codes:

```py
for ID, files_list in d.items():
    codes = [list(file_dict.values())[0] for file_dict in files_list]
    print(codes)
    print(f"The codes for ID {ID} are all equal? {all_equal(codes)}")
```

With your example dict, this is the result:

```
['022012', '022012', '022012', '022012', '022012', '022012', '022012', '022012', '022012', '022012', '349309']
The codes for ID 00068693 are all equal? False
['022012', '022012', '022012', '022012']
The codes for ID 00084737 are all equal? True
```

---

<sup>* `all_equal` above is any of the options in the accepted answer of the duplicate</sup>

Comment: Man, thank you very very much! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dictionary is called `file_codes`, this is how you get the results:

```
for k, v in file_codes.items():
    if len(set([i[j] for i in v for j in i])) != 1:
            print(f"IDS: {k} has different codes")
```