# Why doesn't it print all my list numbers with comma?

Tags: python

```
n=[int(input()) for x in range(int(input()))]
```

Here is part of my code I need a function that tells if all the imported numbers are the same except the number that tells how many numbers there will be.

Here is example of input

```
3
1
1
1
```

I need to tell if 1=1=1
3 means how much elements will be there.
I have tried puting it in for loop `n[i]+n[i+1]` and `n[i]+n[i]` and it didnt do anything or was error

Comment: Please give a [mre], not a vague description.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: it needs to say if all the input nymbers are same(1=1=1) also there in what i have tried needs to be == not +

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if all elements in a list are identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844801/check-if-all-elements-in-a-list-are-identical)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can simply check `len(set(n))==1`:

For example:

```
if len(set(n))==1:
    print("All elements are the same")
else:
    print("All elements are not the same")
```

`True` implies all numbers are the same.

Comment: how can in true place put text that it needs to output

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this

```
n = int(input())
numlist =[int(input()) for x in range(n)] 
if (numlist[0])*n == sum(numlist):
```