# Is there an inbuilt `all or not any` in Python?

Tags: python

Just curious to know if anyone knows of an inbuilt version of:

```
bool_list: List[bool] = # some non-empty list of booleans
result = all(bool_list) or not any(bool_list)

# What I'm looking for
result = allsame(bool_list)
```

Comment: Do you mean like `len(set(bool_list)) == 1`?

Comment: @thefourtheye beautiful. I mean it's still a step above inbuilt but it saves me creating an intermediate variable if my bool_list is generated via list comprehension or some other non-trivial expression.

Comment: Nothing inbuilt but several ways to write it concisely.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3844801/1903116

Comment: @thefourtheye That fails if the list is empty. Also, likely inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Not a built-in but does exactly what you are looking for in an efficient way:

from [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
def all_equal(iterable):
    "Returns True if all the elements are equal to each other"
    g = groupby(iterable)
    return next(g, True) and not next(g, False)
```

Comment: Theirs is efficient, too. I suspect *more* so. And it's simpler.

Comment: The groupby will create a generator, so this will return at the first mismatch and not iterate further.

Comment: True (except it's not a generator but an iterator), but I don't see why you're saying that.