# How to check if a set of keys have the same value?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

Let's say we have a dict

```
dict = {
  "a": "x",
  "b": "x",
  "c": "x",
  "d": "y",
  "e": "y",
  "f": "y",
}
```

How do I quickly check, if a set of specific keys all have the same value?

E.g.:

```
list_of_keys = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

should return True.

```
list_of_keys = ["b", "c", "d"]
```

should return `False`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use built-in [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function and compare all values to the first one:

```
all(dict[k] == dict[list_of_keys[0]] for k in list_of_keys)
```

Another suggestion (from the comments):

```
len(set(dict[k] for k in list_of_keys)) == 1
```

Sidenote: don't use `dict` as a variable name. It's python's built-in.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) and a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set):

```
from operator import itemgetter

len(set(itemgetter(*list_of_keys1)(dic))) == 1
# True

len(set(itemgetter(*list_of_keys2)(dic))) == 1
# False
```

Or, looping over the keys:

```
len(set(dic[k] for k in list_of_keys1)) == 1
# True

len(set(dic[k] for k in list_of_keys2)) == 1
# False
```

Used input:

```
dic = {
  "a": "x",
  "b": "x",
  "c": "x",
  "d": "y",
  "e": "y",
  "f": "y",
}

list_of_keys1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
list_of_keys2 = ["b", "c", "d"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something iterative like this:

```py
def check_if_all_same_value(keys, my_dict):
  value = my_dict[keys[0]]
  for key in keys:
    if my_dict[key] != value:
      return False
  return True
```

This will at first set the reference value to be the one of the first given key. The script will then iterate on the value of each key and, if it is not the same as the reference one, return `False`. If it finishes looping (e.g. if all keys have the same values), the function returns `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [iterools recipy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) ([as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844801/check-if-all-elements-in-a-list-are-identical)) and "list comprehension"

```py
from itertools import groupby

def all_equal(iterable):
    g = groupby(iterable)
    return next(g, True) and not next(g, False)

my_dict = {
  "a": "x",
  "b": "x",
  "c": "x",
  "d": "y",
  "e": "y",
  "f": "y",
}
list_of_keys = ["a", "b", "c"]

ret = all_equal(my_dict[key] for key in list_of_keys)
print(ret)
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick test using `all`:

```
head, *tail = list_of_keys

all(dct[t] == dct[head] for t in tail)
```