# Python functional method of checking that all elements in a list are equal

Tags: python, functional-programming

I am trying to find a functional method which is available in Python which can be used to check if all elements in a list are equal. Instinctively, I feel that this should be possible.

My objective is to build a functional solution to solve the problem of checking if all values in list are equal.

If you search for similar questions on this site you will find both questions and answers, written for Python, but none of these take a functional approach.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256922/discussion-on-question-by-freelanceconsultant-python-functional-method-of-checki); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: What do you mean with "functional method"? I.e., what would / wouldn't you consider functional, how does this differ from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3844801/12671057) for he same "all equal?" task?

Comment: It's really quite unhelpful that the comments were moved to a chat room where I can't reply to them. For those who do not have experience working with functional programming before, please read this wikipedia article to gain a base level understanding. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to others for helping with this. The TL;DR answer: use `starmap`.

Rather than doing everything all at once using a single functional function call, it splits the operations into two steps.

- The first step is to check that adjacent pairs of elements are equal, producing a new list (actually: iterator with yielding behavior) containing boolean values
- The second step is to check if all of the boolean values are true

It seems like the one obvious functional solution, which results in a clean code.

```
input_list [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

import operator
from itertools import pairwise
from itertools import starmap

def all_items_in_list_are_equal(l: list) -> bool:

    all_items_are_equal = \
        all(
            starmap(
                operator.eq,
                pairwise(l)
            )
        )

    return all_items_are_equal
```

This solution is:

- lazy evaluated
- requires only `operator.eq` for the types contained within `l`
- does not require `__hash__`

It works by producing a pairwise iterator `pairwise(l)` which returns pairs of adjacent elements in the list `l` as a tuple.

The tuple is expanded into pairs of arguments by `starmap`. `operator.eq` expects two arguments, so a single argument of type `pair` will not do. We use `starmap` to apply `operator.eq` to every pair of values yield by the iterator.

- `starmap` is to `map` what `func(*args)` is to `func(a, b, c, ...)`

Finally, `all` checks that all elements of an iterable are `True`.

*See edits for history*

Comment: I think this would return True for a list like [1, 1, 2, 2], because of pairwise(l)

Comment: `pairwise` produces `[(1,1), (1,2), (2,2)]`, not `[(1,1), (2,2)]`.

Comment: @Christoph Actually there's another issue with this. It only works for length 3.

Comment: Use `itertools.starmap` instead of `map`. `*pairwise(...)`unpacks the sequence of tuples, not the individual tuples. `all(starmap(operator.eq, pairwise(l)))`.

Comment: I.e, `map(eq, *pairwise([1,2,3]))` is equivalent to `map(eq, (1,2), (2,3), (3,4))`. `starmap(eq, pairwise([1,2,3]))` is equivalent (ignoring the difference between lists and arbitrary iterables) to `starmap(eq, [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)])`.

Comment: Using `map`, you would need something like `map(eq, l, islice(l, 1, None))` (basically, "unzipping" the `pairwise` iterable into separate streams for `map` to iterate over. `map` is more like Haskell's `zipWith` than just a simple mapping function.)

Comment: @chepner thanks, I figured it must be unpacking something differently to how I would have expected - is there a way to "flip" the unpacking? Maybe something involving a zip derivative? (Really just guessing here...)

Comment: You could do `map(eq, *zip(*pairwise(l)))`, but that breaks short-circuiting, as the entire `pairwise` instance (and the `zip` instance) need to be fully iterated before `map` can start applying `eq`. You really just want to use `starmap`, which effectively uncurries `eq` so that you can pull from `pairwise` only as many tuples as `all` needs to return `True` or `False`.

Comment: Just to note, this will also work for empty and singleton lists, as `pairwise([])` and `pairwise([x])` both produce empty sequences, but `all([])` is vacuously true.

Comment: "Finally, all effectively applies a lambda function to check that all elements are True." no?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I didn't understand your comment but I've removed the word `lambda` because that was perhaps misleading.

Answer (score 1):

I Like this

```
def all_elements_equal(lst):
    return all(x == lst[0] for x in lst)
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for something using *only* functions, not special Python syntax. (Though this would be the more idiomatic solution; Python is not strictly a functional language.)

Comment: @Christoph, I was just about to write ```def all_equal( L ): return len( L ) == 0 or L.count( L[0] ) == len( L )``` which would probably have suffered the same depressing fate as your perfectly good answer. So, I've ticked you back up again!

Comment: @lastchance, thank u :) good to know that still some flexibel guys here. Sometimes people Take this to serious ;)

Comment: This solution is perfectly purely functional. Just because it uses seemingly "imperative" syntactic sugar doesn't mean it's not functional. The `for` here works just like `map`, returning an iterator which is lazily evaluated. You could write this as `all(map(lambda x: x == lst[0], lst))` and it would effectively do the same thing. +1 from me.

Comment: @chepner that's silly, though. list comprehensions and related constructs are brought over straight from languages like Haskell

Comment: @Luatic right, now only is it purely functional, the construct itself is ripped straight off of haskell, which no one is going to argue isn't a functional language

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I never said it wasn't, but the original question indicate the OP was looking for a solution using higher-order functions.

Answer (score 0):

So, I tried to implement this using only function calls and splitting `list` to `head|tail`. No library functions, no loops.

```
def all_equal(lst):
    def ale(l, r):
        if l[1:] == []:
            return l[0] == r
        if l[0] != l[1:][0]:
            return False
        return ale(l1, l[0])

    if lst == []:
        return True
    return ale(lst, lst[0])

print(all_equal([1, 1, 1]))
print(all_equal([1, 2, 3]))
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Comment: `l[1:]` is an O(n) copy operation, since Python lists are not recursively defined data structures. Only one is necessary, though: `def ale(l, r): if not l: return True; if l[0] != r: return False; return ale(l[1:], l[0])`.

Comment: I did not care about performance at all, just mimicked strictly functional style.

Comment: @KellyBundy You are right. It should be in  the outer function. Thank you.

Comment: It's not a strictly functional style if you have `if` statements and assignments.

Comment: This is not functional

Comment: @chepner Removed assignments. `if` statements exist in Haskell, Erlang.

Comment: Haskell does not have `if` statements. It uses the keyword `if` to define a conditional expression, which *requires* an else part so that the entire expression is defined regardless of whether the condition is true or not.