# Adding result of a slot machine roll in loop

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that works like a slot machine.  In my loop, I am trying to determine how many credits a player gets based on the result of their spin(s).  However, say when a player rolls and wins 300 credits, when asked to spin again, if they win another time, it doesn't remember the result of the former spin.

I know this is a simple fix, but basically each time the loop goes back again it forgets their updated total.  I am new to programming, and this stuff is confusing as all hell to me.

Here's what I have for the loop section:

```
cashPool = 500

import random

# Assigning wheel properties
wheel1 = ['Candy','Ghost','Pumpkin','Cat','Zombie','Witch','Witch','Cat','Ghost','Candy']
wheel2 = ['Candy','Ghost','Pumpkin','Cat','Zombie','Witch','Cat','Pumpkin','Ghost','Candy']
wheel3 = ['Candy','Ghost','Pumpkin','Cat','Zombie','Witch','Pumpkin','Candy','Candy','Ghost']

#loop to spin


def AskYesNo(question):
    tmp = input(question).lower()
    if tmp.startswith('y'):
        return True
    else:
        return False

i = 0

while True:
    spin1 = random.randint(3,4)
    spin2 = random.randint(3,4)
    spin3 = random.randint(3,4)
    print(str(wheel1[spin1])+ '\t' + str(wheel2[spin2]+ '\t' + str(wheel3[spin3])))
    i += 1
    if spin1==4 and spin2==4 and spin3==4:
        print('Congratulations! You have won 300 credits')
        result = cashPool + 300
        print('You currently have '+ str(result) +' credits')
    if spin1==5 and spin2==5 and spin3==5:
        print('Congratulations! You have won 250 credits')
        result = cashPool + 250
        print('You currently have '+ str(result)+ ' credits')
    if spin1==3 and spin2==3 and spin3==3:
        print('Congratulations! You have won 200 credits')
        result = cashPool + 200
        print('You currently have '+cashPool+' credits')
    if spin1==2 and spin2==2 and spin3==2:
        print('Congratulations! You have won 150 credits')
        result = cashPool + 150
        print('You currently have '+cashPool+' credits')
    if spin1==1 and spin2==1 and spin3==1:
        print('Congratulations! You have won 100 credits')
        result = cashPool + 100
        print('You currently have '+cashPool+' credits')
    if spin1==0 and spin2==0 and spin3==0:
        print('Congratulations! You have won 50 credits')
        result = cashPool + 50
        print('You currently have '+cashPool+' credits')
    AskYesNo('Would you like to spin? Enter y/n ')
    if False:
        break
```

Also, I'm 100% sure there is an easier way to calculate the results of each spin rather than doing if statements over and over.  But again, I'm new, and that's beyond me.  I can't think like a programmer, I don't know how people do it.

Comment: `if False` will never happen... Also, I think you want `cashPool += 300` to update the pool, not assign `result` at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining a new `result` variable, just increment the existing `cashPool` variable you have. E.g.:

```
if spin1==4 and spin2==4 and spin3==4:
    print('Congratulations! You have won 300 credits')
    cashPool += 300 # Here
    print('You currently have '+ str(result) +' credits')
```

Comment: I can't believe I completely forgot += instead of just =.  I swear 95% of the time I come across an issue when I try to program it's literally me forgetting one character or something so minor.

Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `random.randint(3,4)` only returns 3 or 4... needs to be `(0,4)` if you want the rest of the values.

Secondly, this section won't work because `if False` isn't entered ever.

```
AskYesNo('Would you like to spin? Enter y/n ')
if False:
    break
```

You need to get the boolean value from that function.

```
if AskYesNo('Would you like to spin? Enter y/n '):
    break
```

Some other suggestions include not repeating yourself so much. Make it [DRY](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/73065/what-are-dry-kiss-solid-etc-classified-as)

For example, borrowing from

[Python: determine if all items of a list are the same item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787908/python-determine-if-all-items-of-a-list-are-the-same-item)

```
def all_same(items, element):
    return all(x == element for x in items)
```

You can pull out some variable constants, use lists, and some functional programming to check your slots.

This, way, you just play with the numbers and you have a whole different game with minimal changes needed to be made.

```
total_slots = 3
max_range = 4
multiplier = 50

while True:
    i += 1
    spins = [random.randint(0, max_range) for _ in range(total_slots)]
    print('\t'.join(map(str, spins)))

    credits = 0
    for i in range(max_range + 1): # We loop over all spin possible values
        won = all_same(spins, i)
        if won:
            credits = (i + 1) * multiplier #  when i == 0, we add 50
            print('Congratulations! You have won {} credits'.format(credits))
            break #  can stop the for-loop

    cashPool += credits  #  if you didn't win, nothing is added
    print('You currently have {} credits'.format(cashPool))

    if AskYesNo('Would you like to spin? Enter y/n '):
        break
```

Note: I know I didn't include the `wheel` values. That `all_same` method will still work an soon as you get the strings for each `spin` value in the `wheel` lists.